# Compiling documents online

Tags: compiling, tools, online

I have heard rumors that you can compile documents online, and more specifically that Google has a free online compiler, but I have never been able to find any. Is there a way to compile documents online, so that I can write and compile documents even if I don't have a TeX distribution installed on my computer?

Comment: Note the online compiler is not affiliated with google. It simply uses google UI toolkit and google apps hosting platform.

Comment: You mean that you _don't_ carry around a USB with the full TeXLive distribution on it and binaries for all major operating systems?

Comment: @Andrew Stacey lol =) I bet you even have it on your smartphone.

Comment: If you just want equations, check out [Auto-LaTeX Equations for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/), it does all the rendering work for you and looks great.

Comment: @LoopSpace of course I do. This is 2018, after all!

Comment: See also [javascript - texlive.js possible? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101977/texlive-js-possible) ■ Same question on meta site: [Link to online LaTeX compiler - TeX - LaTeX Meta Stack Exchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3164/link-to-online-latex-compiler)

Comment: Looks like there's some kind of service on https://texlive.net/run (first seen in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61512933#61512933 . Not sure how it works though)

Answer (score 314, accepted):

**Online compiler with storage and editor features:**

- [LaTeX Base](https://latexbase.com/)
- [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) *(was WriteLaTeX before)*
- [ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) *(is [joining Overleaf](https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2017/07/20/sharelatex-joins-overleaf.html) since 2017)*
- [WebLaTeX](https://www.github.com/sanjib-sen/weblatex/)
- [Docx2Latex Add-On](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/docx2latex/egbfhgljgndebjfacgpkjchhpfbcpegl?utm_source=permalink) - (Write LaTeX and Rich Text simultaniously in Google Docs)
- [verbosus](https://www.verbosus.com/)
- [Authorea](https://authorea.com/)
- [Papeeria](https://papeeria.com/)
- [\BlueLaTeX](https://github.com/gnieh/bluelatex/) - formally  [publications.li](https://www.publications.li/blue) (meant for Collaborative Writing)
- [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/doc/latex-editor.html) (contains a LaTeX editor amongst many other tools; formerly "SageMathCloud")

*Meanwhile inactive:*

- [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com/) (now uses [ShareLaTeX](http://www.sharelatex.com/) for its editor)
- [SpanDeX](http://www.spandex.io/) (included Dropbox-sync and version control,
  [but has been discontinued](http://www.latex-community.org/home/news/47-news-latex-editors/481-online-latex-compiler-spandex-is-being-discontinued))
- MonkeyTeX: *monkeytex.bradcater.webfactional.com*, seems to not exist any‑more
- [LaTeX Lab](http://latexlab.org/) (does not exist anymore)

**Online compiler with basic functionality:**

- [LaTeX servlet on sciencesoft.at](http://sciencesoft.at/index.jsp?link=latex&js=0&lang=en)
- [LaTeX online-compiler in Halle, Germany](https://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php)
- [TeX on Web](https://tex.mendelu.cz/en/)
- [LaTeX 4 Technics](https://www.latex4technics.com/)
- [Tex Viewer](https://texviewer.herokuapp.com)

**Tiny equation compiler:**

- Google Docs with the [Auto-LaTeX Equations Add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/autolatex_equations/850293439076?utm_source=tex_se_1654) - Write any equation in Google Docs
- [LaTeX equation editor](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-en) with realtime rendering
- [mathurl.com](http://mathurl.com/)
- [Hamline University Physics Department Latex Equation Editor](http://www.hamline.edu/%7Earundquist/equationeditor/)
- [MathTran](http://mathtran.open.ac.uk/) for TeX-notation mathematics
- [Roger's Online Equation Editor](http://rogercortesi.com/eqn/)
- [TeXify](http://www.texify.com/) based on mimeTeX
- [LaTeX2PNG](http://hausheer.osola.com/latex2png)
- [FormulaSheet.com](http://formulasheet.com/editor.php)
- [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](https://www.latex4technics.com/)

**Latex Table generator:**

- [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com)

**Document frame generator:**

- [LaTeX Generator](http://latex.sehnot.de/) (in German)

**The other way round:**

- [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) outputs the corresponding LaTeX command code after you've drawn a symbol
- [classify](http://www.martin-thoma.de/write-math/classify/) has the same purpose like DeTeXify

**Word to LaTeX converters**

- [Docx2Latex](https://www.docx2latex.com) Converts Word/Google Docs file to LaTeX source code and PDF.

Comment: How do you come up with these lists so readily?

Comment: I've been collecting useful links for a long time and I published such lists on my blog. This list comes from my blog page http://texblog.net/latex-link-archive/online-compiler/ with some additions.

Comment: Joseph, since you may refer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162/what-are-other-good-resources-on-line-for-information-about-tex-latex-and-friend for that list I used my resources article of 2007 http://texblog.net/pdf/ressourcen.pdf , also posted on http://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/article.php?sid=1074 , reviewed it and added links found in my blog.

Comment: Is there at least one on this list which supports tikz/pgf? I tried LaTeX Lab and ShareLaTeX but neither of them does. I would also like to know if there is one which supports lualatex. In LaTeX Lab you can define your own distribution but it seems only to work with MikTex.

Comment: @Reza writeLaTeX supports TikZ. I connected the examples from the TikZ gallery on http://texample.net directly to it.

Comment: Very nice links Thanks for sharing.
You could add ownCloud app: Latex Compiler (AGPL)
https://apps.owncloud.com/content/show.php/LatexTex+Editor+and+Compiler?content=151441

Comment: The link for MonkeyTeX is broken: server unreachable. I'm editing the entry to tell.

Comment: The link “LaTeX online-compiler in Halle, Germany” should be re‑checked in the future. Actually, it returns a server error (server still responding though).

Comment: The **Docx2Latex Add-On** link is now broken.

Comment: Looks like **classify**  moved to http://write-math.com/. The original page doesn't work (although the "reverse" list is more suitable for [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara/21#21) -- although both deTeXify and classify/write-math are already mentioned there)

Answer (score 67):

The Google-related solution was available here at http://docs.latexlab.org/ but has been taken offline.

Note, however, that the online compiler was never affiliated with Google. It simply used Google UI toolkit and Google Apps hosting platform. (from [Dima](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/137/dima))

Comment: Website available, but requires access to all your gmail contacts and apparently google documents...

Comment: Hasn't been upgraded to OAuth2.0... unusable

Comment: And now offline...

Answer (score 41):

## [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/)

---

Features:

- registeration required
- collaboration possible, by means of sharing the URL
- documents can be saved, actually everything is saved automatically
- instant compilation on-the-fly
- possibility to upload files (PDF, PNG, STY, TeX, Bib, etc.) up to 10 MiB
- syntax highlighting in the included editor

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Unless I'm missing something the switch to Overleaf v2 after the merger with ShareLaTeX means that the option to use Overleaf without an account is gone. **Registration is now required.**

Answer (score 27):

[ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com/) is another good choice.  You can also checkout the [Common LaTeX Service Interface](http://code.google.com/p/common-latex-service-interface/) (CLSI) which is one of the underlying technologies of both ScribTeX and [LaTeX Lab](http://docs.latexlab.org/).

The CLSI provides the underlying infrastructure for exposing a LaTeX compiler to requests from the internet and can be used to build your own custom web-based solution.

#### Update

ScribTeX uses `git` internally to store revisions to documents and the site's author is planning to open the service up to allow users to push and pull repositories as soon as he gets the logistics worked out.

Looks like there may finally be a GitHub-like service for LaTeX documents!

Comment: I am disappointed at the account structure of ScribTex.  For holding KBs of files, allowing only three projects is quite sad.  My thesis proposal, thesis and resume already used up the three projects and I am definitely not paying for more projects for such a basic service.

Answer (score 23):

The [ConTeXtGarden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page) offers a simple [ConTeXt online compiler](http://live.contextgarden.net/). It uses an up-to-date ConTeXt MkIV version (LuaTeX).

Here is a screenshot (of an older version which still offered the choice to compile with MkII):

[image: contextlivenew]

Comment: Down these days :/

Comment: Meanwhile MkII has disappeared from ConTeXt live.

Answer (score 16):

[Verbosus](http://www.verbosus.com/) seems to be the most convenient and appealing to me.

It worth noting that Verbosus has a good app for smartphone and tablet (with a dark theme, which someone may prefer) and, last but not least, use an updated version of TeX Live, whereas Overleaf and ShareLaTeX do not.

On the other hand, it has not the instant compilation on-the-fly, which Overleaf has.

Answer (score 11):

A recent addition to online compilers by Troy Henderson, presented at [TUGboat 33:1, 2012](http://www.tug.org/tugboat/Contents/contents33-1.html) is the [LaTeX previewer](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I’ve used some of the online compilers, and they’re fine, but occasionally I want to make use of my own TeX installation on my work computer because it has custom packages and settings installed not available with the online compiler. But what to do if I’m not sitting in front of my work computer?

My solution was to set up a SSH server on my work computer, and simply use an SSH client from wherever I am to log in, fire up vim or emacs or other text only text editor to do edits if need be, and/or simply run latex/pdflatex from the commandline through the shell.

Apparently, you can do this with an iPad or similar. (I don't have one.)

Comment: You can forward X11 over ssh pretty easily so no need to confine yourself to command line editors if you don't wish to, at least on GNU/Linux and Mac OS X. One big advantage of this is security. I've yet to find an online compiler I would trust my work to simply for reasons of privacy. People should think more carefully about the implications of this stuff, especially in light of recent events.

Answer (score 9):

One more solution, not mentioned above: [papeeria.com](http://papeeria.com/)
It's currently in active development.
**Free plan** includes one private project and unlimited public ones.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[SimpleLaTeX](http://www.simplelatex.com/): A simple online editor for very minimal documents; manages and previews LaTeX notes:

SimpleLaTeX is an online tool where you can preview and share short notes in LaTeX. It may be useful if you are writing a complicated equation, table, or TikZ image that requires iterative trial-and-error. Current features include:

- A trimmed image is generated and displayed in scalable SVG;
- Images in PDF and PNG formats are also available for download;
- You can save your note being sketched to your browser's cache, which will be loaded next time you visit;
- You can publish your compilable note and share it with others.

The site requires HTML5 support so it may not work in older browsers.

SimpleLaTeX is not designed to handle full LaTeX documents such as [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) does. The goal is to be light-weight and in spirit more like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Amusingly, many of the online previewers given in other answers are vulnerable to maliciously crafted input. I can only think of one fairly-far fetched way this could be a problem for users, but the people running the preview services should think long and hard about what it is they're doing.

Comment: They really should. I considered hosting one for my own personal use, then realised what a wretched, massive security hole it would be and decided against it.

Comment: @EricR: could you perhaps elaborate on how to make it safe? or what the problems are? if \write18 is disabled, is it any better? without actually giving malicious code, could you provide some pointers as to what some problematics commands could be?

Comment: @Yossi: Sure. Joseph's [blog](http://www.texdev.net/2010/04/25/tex-and-security/) mentions a paper that describes this in some detail.

Comment: See also another question on the site [online - How can I safely compile other people's LaTeX documents? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10418/how-can-i-safely-compile-other-peoples-latex-documents)

Answer (score 6):

I think that my minimalistic service, [latex-online](http://latex.aslushnikov.com), might come handy to someone.

Unique feature:

- Create a **live link** which, when pressed, fetches content from url/git repo and returns freshly compiled pdf. [Github example](http://latex.aslushnikov.com/compile?git=git://github.com/aslushnikov/diplom-latex.git&target=diplom.tex)

This helps a lot if you store TeX files in a public repository and want a "See Latest" link in the README.md (example: [my diploma](https://github.com/aslushnikov/diplom-latex#readme)).

Other than that, main features are:

- Compile given URL/gitrepo/text.
- Compile local files (with the help of [command-line utility](https://github.com/aslushnikov/latex-online/blob/master/util/laton)
- Open Source!
- Easy docker deployment

I find this useful - but once again, beware: I'm the developer of the thing and might be biased.

Comment: Internal Server Error 500 here on 2016-Nov-12.

Comment: @JimHefferon thanks for the heads-up, it got fixed some time ago. Should be working fine now

Answer (score 5):

Another solution not mentioned here is [Authorea](https://authorea.com) which lets you collaboratively write LaTeX (and Markdown), and render it to HTML or PDF (most journal styles supported). Also- it is built on Git for version control.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's another one I found:

http://tools.jcisio.com/tex/eq.html

Answer (score 4):

[I've blogged about using CLSI](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/07/compiling-latex-without-local-latex.html) (in particular ScribTeX) to compile LaTeX remotely. I wrote a little client in F#, but it's pretty easy to code a CLSI client in any language.

I also show conceptually in that article how to integrate this with a source control repository and a build server.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, Verbosus not only allows using LaTeX in the browser. The developers also provide an Android app called [VerbTeX](https://www.verbosus.com/android-latex-editor.html) and an iPad/iPhone app called [iVerbTeX](https://www.verbosus.com/ios-latex-editor-for-ipad-and-iphone.html). I guess this is definitely a nice addition to browser-based LaTeX editing.

Answer (score 3):

Texpad developers here. I should add that remote/cloud typesetting has become increasingly unnecessary as on iOS we have our universal (iPad/iPhone/iPod Touch) app called Texpad that has the most complete local LaTeX typesetter with advanced fonts, Beamer and tikz.

Hope it helps to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

The following is the only LaTeX online editor that I found both to be **100% free** and to **support collaborative editing**. It was also designed for sharing bibliography, but I have not looked into that feature.

[www.publications.li/](http://www.publications.li/)

All you have to do is register and you are ready to start a document. To share the document with an "unconstrained" number of collaborators, just send them the document's URL. I think it is worth the try.

Comment: At the moment, the https://publications.li/ domain is up for sale.

Answer (score 3):

For the MetaPost users, besides Troy Henderson's [LaTeX previewer](http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/) already presented above there is also its [MetaPost previewer](http://www.tlhiv.org/mppreview/):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs

For just equations, the [Auto-Latex Equations add-on for Google Docs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3) is free and works brilliantly. Additionally, it replaces all your equations with images of the high-quality equation, making it mobile-viewable and fully compatible with Google Docs image tools.

All you have to do is type an equation within delimiters, like $$55 + \sqrt{5}$$ and it can be rendered in super high quality at whatever time you like by rendering all the equations in your document. If you mess up, you can always undo one or all the equations. It supports collaborative editing, but not the full LaTeX document syntax.

You can get it for free at [the Google Docs add-ons store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-latex-equations/iaainhiejkciadlhlodaajgbffkebdog?utm_source=tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3).

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use a [LaTeX API](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api) to compile the tex files online. DynamicDocs is JSON to PDF API which utilises LaTeX to create PDFs. DynamicDocs API features include:

- Ready-made [JSON to PDF](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/json-to-pdf-templates) templates (no LaTeX required)
- Ability to write your own template online in LaTeX and merge JSON to
  PDF using the R language layer, making the templates and their
  content dynamic
- Pass your own tex file in the JSON payload to the [Tex to PDF with pdfLaTeX v1](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/json-to-pdf-templates/pub-tex-to-pdf-with-pdflatex-v1) endpoint to compile the PDF with pdfLaTeX
- Each account is given a FREE plan with a limited number of monthly
  API calls

Disclaimer: I am involved in developing DynamicDocs API.