# How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character?

Tags: symbols

I know what my symbol or character looks like, but I don't know what the command is or which math alphabet it came from. How do I go about finding this out?

Comment: @AlanMunn -- asking you since you edited the question ... maybe "extend" the title to "how to look up a symbol or the style of a math alphabet"?  many, many questions are about alphabet styles, not just other symbols, and this doesn't seem to be obvious.

Comment: Related: [What are all the font styles I can use in math mode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/58098/5764)

Comment: Note: ■ deTeXify only helps with finding symbol, not determining the font. So it cannot e.g. finding characters in commercial font,
e.g. [Adobe Minion Pro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/640360). See also: [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45919) 
■ deTeXify appears to use DTW as the algorithm and unfortunately currently is sensitive to both order of strokes and direction of strokes. (try look up `⊛`. You need to draw it in order `○\/|` and the `○` needs to be drawn counter clockwise for the correct symbol to be shown on top.)

Answer (score 867, accepted):

1. You can look things up in the [**Comprehensive LaTeX symbols**](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) list. It can usually be easily accessed with `texdoc symbols` or `texdoc symbols-a4` (in MiKTeX the latter only).
2. Another good option is to try the web-based software [**Detexify**](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which allows you to draw the symbol and tries to recognize what you've drawn. Here is a screenshot:

   > [image: Screenshot]
3. If you are using the package [`unicode-math`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), then besides using any Unicode character list, the [**list of all supported symbols**](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) (`texdoc unimath-symbols`) is very useful as it also lists which symbols are available in the various fonts.
4. Using [`unicode-math`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), you can also search for characters by drawing (just like with detexify) using [**ShapeCatcher**](http://shapecatcher.com/).

<sub>The above techniques provide an adequate way of finding symbols but are not necessarily foolproof since you sometimes need to know what you're looking for in order to find it. For example, in [Typing Following notation in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132453) it may not be apparent that "vector fields in differential geometry" are somehow related to "bowties". To that end, searching for a symbol rotated 90 degrees or flipped horizontally, say, might lead you in the right direction.</sub>

Comment: Yup, Detexify has become *the* best way to do this

Comment: Detexify is particularly useful if you get it on a device with a touch screen (there are Android/iPhone apps for it) -- personally, I find it rather difficult to draw with my mouse, but finger works fine :)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `Select from the complete list!` link in the results list will display the symbols list ordered by score, so it's more useful than the intimidating term `complete list` might suggest.

Comment: Detexify just led me to [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_decomposition#Normal_matrices). I struggled to find the meaning of "upside down V" for hours last night.

Comment: @DavidPoole: For Wikipedia articles, try clicking the `[edit]` button. It will show you the source, for math it is almost the same as LaTeX. It's a nice way to find out certain things, and also usefull for copying entire formulas ;)

Comment: I don't know the current state, but Detexify has been mining bitcoins using a [Javascript implemented](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=9042.0) bitcoin miner. (Source: http://blog.fefe.de/?ts=b31bb8ad)

Comment: Note to oneself: when it is in a more advanced level, think to speak of [http://martin-thoma.de/write-math/](http://martin-thoma.de/write-math/).

Comment: I could not make Detexify recognize my drawn `\curvearrowright`. I did a Google search for "Latex curved arrow" and found what I was looking for on a random page. My point is that Google is your friend, and that it could be considered as a fourth method.

Comment: Given the disdain for this question, what other options are available after trying (and failing) with Detexify, LaTeX Font Catalog, Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, typography identification sites, and general Googling (up to about two hours of cumulative time thus far) to identify one character? (I was going to ask on Meta, but the question is hated there too. Seems rather a dead end.)

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL , have you tried http://martin-thoma.de/write-math/?

Comment: @inavda Of course, repeatedly. It simply doesn't work.

Comment: That's too bad :( maybe make a post and see if anyone is able to identify it?

Comment: Detexify is not simply working. I myself prefer mathcha.io .

Answer (score 159):

Theres lots of ways of doing this, but the two I've found to be most useful are these:

- [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) Allows you to draw the symbol, and then guesses based on similar symbols.  This is great for me because I don't always remember the name of the symbol, and even if I know the name, I may not have the *correct* name.
- [AMS LaTeX Short Math Guide](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) This short pdf gives an overview of AMS LaTeX functionality, and includes a pretty thorough list of *most* of the math symbols (un)commonly used in proofs and formulas.

Comment: +1 for the magic combination of detexify and the AMS guide

Comment: Detexify is great, but I wouldn't say that the coverage of the Short Math Guide for LaTeX is representative.

Comment: Your link to the AMS LaTeX Short Math Guide appears to be broken.  [This](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex) appears to be the home page, but it, too lists the same FTP address.  The entire site ftp.ams.org is there and you can connect with FTP, but you can't retrieve a site listing or change directory.

Answer (score 100):

The old school way is to look it up in the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) (**warning:** 4 MB PDF file).

The new hotness is to use [DeTeXify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) which uses handwriting recognition to look the symbol up for you.

DeTeXify even comes in an iPhone/Andriod app- you can get a free version or pay for one.  The only difference is that with the paid app you are making a donation to the developer- the feature set is exactly the same.

The author is planning to work on a mobile version of the website [that will supplant](http://detexify.posterous.com/the-road-ahead-20) these apps.

Comment: When you see a warning about a 4 MP download in 2018, you can only guess how much the world of the Internet has changed in the last decade. I remember when clicking on a download encompassing more than the dreaded 1'000'000 bytes was worth going afk and making coffee. Today, it took me 3 seconds to load that PDF (on my school's network, admittedly, but it wouldn't be *much* different at home.)

Comment: It looks like the iPhone app was made unavailable in the US AppStore some years ago, and it still is as of today.

Answer (score 91):

I often look up the relevant topic on Wikipedia, (e.g. [Set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory)) and look at the source there. Wikipedia uses LaTeX for math markup as well.

Comment: This has the advantage that you also get advice on whether others are using the symbol you had in mind for this role. You may find many people use something else--which you might prefer once you see it.

Answer (score 74):

For uncommon symbols, instead of search documentation on-line or in a big PDF to find packages and commands to include in my code, I have found useful sometimes  to compile the whole table of characters of a font (even in the working document) to quickly find, for example, the skull of the `omding` font  that is `\char194`. Of course, you have first to know that you have a font file with that name (`omding.tfm`) but then is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\begin{document}
\fonttable{omding}
\font\omding=omding
\omding  \char194
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]
You can also search for a skull the in Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list, or paint a skull  in Detexify, or remember the easy command "`\skull`" (and  do not forget load the `skull` package and enter in math mode) o  try to find a `\dingbat`  or `\ding{`whatever`}`... but when I want a skull (really never) must be that of white bones (just try the other methods if you don't know what I mean).

Answer (score 36):

There's also an iPhone app for Detexify, which I've used occasionally, for some reason ...

Links (on the US iTunes App Store): [free version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/detexify/id328805329) and [supporter version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/detexify-supporter-version/id328800612) ($0.99, same functionality).

Comment: This item seems no longer available in the US Store.  Pity.

Answer (score 36):

### TL;DR

[Direct link to the online service](http://write-math.com/) (currently down; look below to run this on your machine)

This service allows classification by drawing (even works on mobile devices!) and by text:

[image]

### Some information

The handwriting recognition toolkit (`hwrt`) is one possibility to classify you recordings. There are still many rough edges and the software gets updated on a daily basis (04.12.2014). The user interface is in a browser and looks like this:

[image]

The [installation](http://pythonhosted.org/hwrt/installation.html) is explained in the documentation. If you have trouble or have an idea how to improve it, just leave a comment or write an email (info@martin-thoma.de).

This is a part of my bachelor's thesis. The thesis, some presentations and links to all software projects are on http://martin-thoma.com/write-math/

Comment: Hehe, I would list the same results even as a human for this drawing

Comment: after using `python -m pip install hwrt` it starts installing. I'll feedback later.

Comment: @ moose I'm sorry but now `error: package directory hwrt does not exist` appears when I try to install by `python setup.py install`. Maybe it would be easier to provide a complete portable version for testing (without third party modules needed).

Comment: @TimS. Is this still a problem? Could we talk about it via email (info@martin-thoma.de) or via GitHub issue?

Comment: Thanks, this is wonderful work.

Answer (score 33):

I've just come across this list http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/unimathsymbols.pdf which lists characters using unicode numbers, their representation, and their (La)TeX command, together with other useful information.

Here's a random sample of what it looks like:

[image: symbol list including unicode]

Comment: This seems also to be useful: http://mirror.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/utf8-macro-map.html.

Answer (score 27):

In case you are using TeXstudio or Texmaker, you can browse the built-in catalog of symbols and find the symbol you need in the appropriate category of symbols (see the image below). It is very convenient, as by clicking on the symbol it gets automatically inserted into your document.

[image: TeXstudio symbol catalog]

Moreover, if you're using TeXstudio on Windows, you can use `Wizards` -> `Math Assistant...` which enables you to draw symbols and it translates them into text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, are any plugins similar to Math-Assistant available for linux?

Answer (score 26):

[This reference](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) has yet to fail me; it has all the symbols typeset along with the `\foo` command needed to generate them. There's also [this PDF](http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A//amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/Symbols.pdf), which is considerably better put-together and covers other symbols besides the base math ones

Answer (score 25):

The LaTeX wikibook [Mathematics](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) section has been very helpful for me.

Answer (score 18):

Some utilities for lookup symbols in Unicode:

- [ent2latex](http://llg.cubic.org/docs/ent2latex.html): A Perl script to translate Unicode symbols to LaTeX commands. (However, it doesn't utilize math fonts.)
- [kcharset](http://utils.kde.org/projects/kcharselect/): A KDE application to lookup Unicode. (Well, you can input some symbols in Unicode directly, or lookup the corresponding LaTeX command by ent2latex.)

Answer (score 16):

I use the Daum Equation editor then just copy and paste the code at the bottom (you can specify Tex,LaTeX, etc.) and even favourite the equations/symbols to avoid having to re-look them up every time you use them. 
Not sure if they have EVERY symbol, but it has been a good reference for me so far!

Answer (score 14):

[`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) provides access to a host of web-related icons (or symbols) provided by the included Font Awesome font.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

These are some symbols from the font \texttt{FontAwesome}:

\faBicycle\
\faCodeFork\
\faDiamond\
\faFirefox\
\faFortAwesome\
\faGears\
\faJsfiddle\
\faLinux

\end{document}
```

However, if you want access to the latest-and-greatest web-related icons from the font and are running XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you can [download the font directly](http://fontawesome.io/). Here you can also [search the list of available icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) to identify a symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\fa}{FontAwesome_0.otf}% http://fontawesome.io/

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

These are some symbols from the font \texttt{FontAwesome}:

\fa
\symbol{"F2B9} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/address-book/
\symbol{"F2DC} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/snowflake-o/
\symbol{"F2C5} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/free-code-camp/
\symbol{"F2CC} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/shower/
\symbol{"F2DD} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/superpowers/
\symbol{"F2D6} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/grav/
\symbol{"F2C6} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/telegram/
\symbol{"F2CE} % http://fontawesome.io/icon/podcast/

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

To the long list of answers provided how to identify a character using online tools I can suggest to use also:

- [**Shapecatcher**](http://shapecatcher.com/) very similar to **Detexify**, where you can find in addition to Unicode characters also `LaTeX` characters (see the symbol of the `\beta` near the chick).
  [image]
- [Drawing Font Checker](https://warehouse.tekla.com/#!/catalog/details/u136b2f44-20dd-40f3-93f6-ce720a71ddf1) by Tekla apparently free software that allows you to detect fonts using an image.

Answer (score 7):

Referring to the answer of the user @Werner, there is also a supplement as increased of the package `fontawesome`, called [`fontawesome5`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf) of Marcel Krüger.
[image: Screenshot from documentation]

This is a small table as example,
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Some fontawesome5 symbols}
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
\faArtstation & \faAtom \\ \hline
\faGoogleDrive &  \faBowlingBall \\ \hline
\faBroom &  \faCarrot\\ \hline
\faCheese &  \faFrog\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *Awesome* answer, btw!

Answer (score 5):

If you use Mac, there is an app named "Texpad 2" from which you can pick most symbols:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

My book "Schnell and Ziel mit LaTeX2e" (only available in German) has a symbol index with a lookup method inspired by Chinese dictionaries: The mathematical symbols are ordered by the number and type of strokes needed to draw them. The index includes the symbols from plain TeX, AMS symbols, and LaTeX symbols.

As far as I know, this index has not been copied by other authors.