# What are other good resources on-line for information about TeX, LaTeX and friends?

Tags: big-list, online, resources

Are there newsgroups, forums, FAQs, and other sites that provide quality information on TeX, LaTeX and friends?  Are all of these in English, or is there one in "my language of choice"?

Comment: What is your "language of choice"?

Comment: I think this question is borderline to be closed, almost too general (indeed, which language, are we going to list all resources in all languages?) In any case, it *should* be made a community wiki.

Comment: There's this one site called something like "tex.stackexchange.com" or something? I've heard that's pretty good...

Comment: I think that this should be community wiki, and Stefan's answer should be accepted so that it stays at the top.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Newsgroups:**

- [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/topics): Usenet discussion group for TeX and LaTeX
- [de.comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.de/group/de.comp.text.tex/topics): German Usenet discussion group for TeX and LaTeX
- [fr.comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.de/group/fr.comp.text.tex/topics): French Usenet group
- [es.comp.lenguajes.tex](https://groups.google.com/group/es.comp.lenguajes.tex/topics): Spanish Usenet group

**Web forums:**

- [TeX, LaTeX and friends](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) on Stack Exchange
- [TeXWelt](https://texwelt.de/): in German, with format and organization very similar to TeX.SE
- [LaTeX.org](https://latex.org/): LaTeX-dedicated web forum
- [goLaTeX Deutsch](https://golatex.de/): German LaTeX forum, with Wiki
- [TeXnique.fr](https://texnique.fr): a French TeX Q&A site
- [mrunix.de](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=38): today less frequented German LaTeX subforum of a programmers site
- [qa.parsilatex.com](http://qa.parsilatex.com/): in Persian

**Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ):**

- [TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org): FAQ sponsored by the UK TeX Users Group, formerly maintained by Robin Fairbairns
- [The Visual LaTeX FAQ](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/visualFAQ/visualFAQ.pdf): formatting samples available through a hyperlink interface
- [MacTeX FAQ](https://tug.org/mactex/faq/): Mac OS X specific questions and answers
- [AMS FAQ](http://www.ams.org/authors/author-faq.html): FAQ for AMS-LaTeX, primarily for AMS authors, but also dealing with `amsmath` and with LaTeX in general
- [de-tex-faq](https://mirrors.ctan.org/info/german/detexfaq/detexfaq.pdf): FAQ of the German TeX user group DANTE e.V.
- [Picture FAQ](http://www.ctan.org/get/info/l2picfaq/german/l2picfaq.pdf): How to Include Pictures, in German

**Software and Package Archives and Catalogues:**

- [CTAN - The Comprehensive TeX Archive Network](https://www.ctan.org/): the authoritative collection of materials related to TeX and LaTeX
- [The TeX Catalogue Online](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/): TeX/LaTeX package catalogue with topical, hierarchical, brief and alphabetical index
- [TeX Resources on the Web](http://www.tug.org/interest.html): Collection by the TeX User Group
- [The LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/): displays nearly all free fonts available for use with LaTeX

**Wikis:**

- [The LaTeX Wiki book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX) on wikibooks.org
- [goLaTeX wiki](https://golatex.de/wiki/index.php?title=Hauptseite): German wiki with language reference and package information

**Mailing lists:**

- [texhax](https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/texhax): the original TeX mailing list, going back to the 1980's
- [mailing lists of the TeX Users Group](https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo): around 50 lists on tug.org for general subjects and certain packages
- [mailing lists on gmane.org](http://gmane.org/lists.php): among many lists there are several TeX related mailing lists
- [ctan-ann - CTAN Announcements](http://www.mail-archive.com/ctan-ann@dante.de/): announcements of the Comprehensive TeX Archive Network: updates, new packages etc.
- [pgf-users](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pgf-users): mailing list for pgf/TikZ
- [Typo-L](https://listserv.heanet.ie/lists/typo-l.html): discussion of type and typographic design
- [tex-d-l](http://www.listserv.dfn.de/archives/tex-d-l.html): German mailing list for TeX and LaTeX

**User group sites**:

- [TUG - TeX Users Group](http://www.tug.org/)
- [UK-TUG](http://uk-tug-archive.tug.org/): TeX in the United Kingdom
- [DANTE e.V.](https://www.dante.de/): German users group
- [The LaTeX Project](http://www.latex-project.org/)
- [more groups](https://www.tug.org/usergroups.html) listed by the TUG
- [ParsiLaTeX](http://parsilatex.com/): Iranian users group

**Blogs:**

- [TeXblog](https://texblog.net/): News and information by Stefan Kottwitz
- [Some TeX Developments](https://www.texdev.net/): blog by LaTeX developer Joseph Wright
- [LaTeX Alive](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/): blog by Will Robertson
- [LaTeX for Humans](http://latexforhumans.wordpress.com/): Tips, resources and tutorials
- [texblog | because LaTeX matters](http://texblog.org/)
- more to be found on [texample.net/community](https://www.texample.net/community/)

**Distributions** - where to get a complete TeX system:

- [TeX Live](https://tug.org/texlive/): TeX system for Linux, Unix, Mac OS X and Windows
- [MiKTeX](https://www.miktex.org/): user-friendly TeX system for Windows
- [proTeXt](https://tug.org/protext/): easy-to-install distribution for Windows, based on MiKTeX
- [MacTeX](http://tug.org/mactex/): TeX Live customized for Mac OS X with useful additions

**Editors:**

- Cross-platform: [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/), [TeXworks](http://tug.org/texworks/), [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/)
- Windows: [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/), [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) ([community](http://www.winedt.org/)), [LEd](http://www.latexeditor.org/), [LaTeX-Editor](http://www.meshwalk.com/latexeditor/), [WinShell](http://www.winshell.de/)
- Linux: [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/), [gedit](http://www.gnome.org/projects/gedit/) and [plugin](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/LaTeXPlugin)
- Mac OS X: [TeXShop](http://www.uoregon.edu/%7Ekoch/texshop/)
- Also see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)

**Viewers:**

- see [Output viewers topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2006/output-viewers-for-use-with-latex) for all platforms and formats

**Friends:** - Software related to TeX and LaTeX

- The [ConTeXt Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page)
- [LyX homepage](http://www.lyx.org/) and [wiki](http://wiki.lyx.org/)
- [LuaTeX](http://www.luatex.org/)
- [GNU TeXmacs](http://www.texmacs.org/)

Comment: Nice, complete list (I was half-way through voting for lots of other answers when I spotted this one!)

Comment: One thing that is mssing is the german LaTeX forum at mrunix.de (http://mrunix.de/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=38).

Comment: The mrunix forum is great. I just did not include LaTeX subforums (mrunix is a general programmers forum) but LaTeX dedicated forums. More such subforums are listed here: http://texblog.net/latex-link-archive/board-forum-group/

Comment: mrunix-LaTeX is only a subforum, but its topics account for about 60% of mrunix.de. Also, it has (at the moment) about 10 times the content of golatex.de.

Comment: That is one hell of a list. **Very** good work!

Comment: I have new package idea, but can't implement it. Where or whom should I tell the idea to implement the idea?

Comment: @alhelal You could post it do a discussion forum, where people can talk about it. For example: [LaTeX.org](http://latex.org). In that case I can also blog about it, many programmers read blogs via feed readers or collectors. Or you write yourself a blog post on [TeX-talk.net](http://tex-talk.net).

Answer (score 14):

http://wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX

And you can even help improving it yourself :)

Answer (score 11):

The [TeX FAQ](http://texfaq.org), where you'll the answer to what you're looking for surprisingly often.

Answer (score 11):

For drawing figures using TikZ [texample](http://www.texample.net) is a great resource for examples, complete with code.

Answer (score 8):

The two big ones are http://www.latex-community.org/ and http://tug.org/.
And the site you're on right now, of course!

Answer (score 6):

The `#latex` IRC channel on freenode.net has some extremely knowledgeable people on it.

Answer (score 5):

Ladies and Gentlemen!

Without further ado
we proudly present

**the very best resource for TeX and friends**:

`texdoc <packagename>`

**on a commandline.**

This is it. There is nothing better.

Answer (score 4):

One of my favourite books on LaTeX is 'The LaTeX companion'. It has the whole 3rd chapter 113 pages freely online (See: [full text of chapter 3](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/tlc2-ch3.pdf)). The typography is also excellent.

Answer (score 4):

No one has talked about "Friends" so far :-)

For ConTeXt, the ConTeXt [wiki](http://www.contextgarden.net) is pretty useful

Answer (score 3):

There are also options on usenet: the newsgroups comp.text.tex, fr.comp.text.tex (French), de.comp.text.tex (German) are also places where questions can be asked. Moreover, announcements about new and updated packages are also sent there.

Answer (score 3):

For LaTeX the way it's used by linguists, there is 
http://www.essex.ac.uk/linguistics/external/clmt/latex4ling/

Comment: This makes me wonder: Should there be a thread collecting information about LaTeX concerning different sciences?

Answer (score 3):

For philosophers and others in the humanities there is [the PhilTeX blog](http://charlietanksley.net/philtex) and [the PhilTeX forum](http://charlietanksley.net/philtex/forum).

Answer (score 2):

German resources for LuaTeX: http://www.luatex.de/ressourcen/

Answer (score 2):

A good website to take the first steps with LaTeX is https://www.learnlatex.org/

It is currently available in the following languages:

- Català
  (Catalan)
- Deutsch
  (German)
- English
  (English)
- Español
  (Spanish)
- Français
  (French)
- मराठी
  (Marathi)
- Português
  (Portuguese)
- Tiếng Việt
  (Vietnamese)