# bibtex error Texshop

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, jurabib

I have the following files my main file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}                  
\geometry{a4paper}                    
\usepackage{wutzi}


\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\makeindex
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false,
citecolor=Violet,
linkcolor=Red,
urlcolor=Blue}
\title{Vorlage}
\author{Wutzi}
\date{\today}   
\maketitle

\begin{center}\\ \\ \\ \\ \\
{\Huge \color{red} \textbf{ DON'T PANIC}}
\end{center}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage  

\cite{tipler}

\bibliographystyle{jurabib}

\begin{thebibliography}
\bibliography{bib}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

The package wutzi looks like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{wutzi}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{underlin}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

%convenience  Definitions   %%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\L}{\mathcal L}%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb C}%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\H}{\mathcal H}%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}
\renewcommand{\grad}{\operatorname{grad}}%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\div}{\operatorname{div}}%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\rot}{\operatorname{rot}}%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\<}{\langle}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\>}{\rangle}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\rho}{\varrho}%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\lag}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial {#2}_j} - \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial #1}{\partial \dot {#2}_j}}%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\done}{\begin{flushright}$\square$ \end{flushright}}
\renewcommand{\scalar}[2]{\< {#1},{#2}\>}
\renewcommand{\Int}[2]{\int\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
\renewcommand{\DGL}{Differentialgleichung }
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}
\renewcommand{\LT}{Legendre-Transformation }
\renewcommand{\brac}[2]{#1^{(#2)}}
\renewcommand{\HJG}{Hamilton-Jacobi-Gleichung }
\renewcommand{\d}{\operatorname{d}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rmnum}[1]{\romannumeral #1}
\newcommand{\Rmnum}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

That's the bib.bib file:

```
@book{Landau,
Author = {E.M. Lifschitz, Lew Davidowitsch Landau},
Date-Added = {2011-06-07 22:38:33 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2011-06-07 22:40:47 +0200},
Keywords = {Landau Theorie},
Publisher = {NAUKA Verlag},
Read = {1},
Title = {Lehrbuch der theoretischen Physik},
Year = {1988}}

@book{metzler,
Author = {J.Grehn, J.Krause(Hrsg.)},
Date-Added = {2011-06-07 22:37:04 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2011-06-07 22:38:10 +0200},
Keywords = {metzler Physik},
Publisher = {Metzler},
Title = {Physik},
Year = {1998}}

@book{LineareAlgebra,
Author = {Albrecht Beutelspacher},
Date-Added = {2011-06-07 22:34:00 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2011-06-07 22:36:53 +0200},
Keywords = {Lineare Algebra},
Publisher = {Vieweg+Teuber},
Read = {1},
Title = {Lineare Algebra},
Year = {2003}}

@book{tipler,
Author = {Paul A. Tipler},
Date-Added = {2011-06-07 22:31:58 +0200},
Date-Modified = {2011-06-07 22:33:44 +0200},
Keywords = {Tipler Physik},
Publisher = {Spektrum Akademischer Verlag},
Read = {1},
Title = {Physik},
Volume = {1.Auflage},
Year = {2000}}
```

And finally the aux file:

```
\relax 
\catcode`"\active
\providecommand\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\AtBeginDocument}
\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\global\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline
\gdef\contentsline#1#2#3#4{\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\global\let\oldnewlabel\newlabel
\gdef\newlabel#1#2{\newlabelxx{#1}#2}
\gdef\newlabelxx#1#2#3#4#5#6{\oldnewlabel{#1}{{#2}{#3}}}
\AtEndDocument{\ifx\hyper@anchor\@undefined
\let\contentsline\oldcontentsline
\let\newlabel\oldnewlabel
\fi}    
\fi}
\global\let\hyper@last\relax 
\gdef\HyperFirstAtBeginDocument#1{#1}
\providecommand\HyField@AuxAddToFields[1]{}
\select@language{ngerman}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{ngerman}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{ngerman}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{ngerman}}
\citation{tipler}
\bibstyle{jurabib}
```

When I run bibtex - after I ran pdftex at least two times - I get an error:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2010)
The top-level auxiliary file: Vorlage.aux
The style file: jurabib.bst
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Vorlage.aux
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "tipler"
(There was 1 error message)
```

If I check the aux file I can see, that there is no \bibdata command, but why and how do i get it to be there. Have I done anything wrong? I'm using Texshop and Bibdesk to create my files. The Texdistribution in Mactex 2010 (Texlive).

Comment: This is really not the best way to ask a question. You got lucky this time, because the solution to you problem is quite obvious, but for future questions, you really need to learn to construct *small* examples which only load the absolutely minimally required packages to show the problem.  In your case, that means taking out all of the extra packages in your personal style file. The minimal document would have used *just* the `natbib` package and the `jurabib` bib style, and one citation.

Answer (score 7):

You have two problems. One, as Ian points out, is that you should not use

```
 \begin{thebibliography}
   ...
 \end{thebibliography}
```

when you are using BiBTeX.  But this won't solve your problem directly.  You are trying to use the `jurabib` bibliography style with the [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package.  This simply won't work, since the `jurabib` style only works with the [`jurabib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/jurabib) package.

However, if you are looking for Author/Year citations, the `jurabib` style is not the correct style anyway, and you should try one of the standard `natbib` styles like `plainnat` or `kluwer` (or one of the many `.bst` files for various journals in your field.)

So instead of

```
\bibliographystyle{jurabib}
```

you should use

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
```

If you truly need Humanities style referencing of the sort that the `jurabib` package implements,  I strongly urge you to consider using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) rather than `jurabib`, which is no longer being developed.

Comment: There are, in fact, more problems: the use of the sequence ` \\ \\ \\ \\ `, the redefinition of non-existing commands, and the list goes on. Unfortunately, I don't have time right now to review the whole list.

Comment: @Gonzalo, Yes, indeed. But for the specific problem of the error, this should solve it.  But you're right, there's a host of other bad coding practices. Benedikt, you should get yourself some good introductory materials on LaTeX. See answers [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693) and also [Best practices references](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/577/2693).

Answer (score 5):

Delete `\begin{thebibliography}` and `\end{thebibliography}`. They are used when you construct the bibliography environment yourself, not when using `BiBTeX`.