# What is best method to insert an ellipsis in a (Xe)TeX document?

Tags: punctuation

What is best method to insert an ellipsis in a (Xe)TeX document?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
a...b a ... b %or

a\ldots b a \ldots  b %or

a…b a … b  

$a...b  a ... b$ %or

$a\ldots b  a \ldots  b $ %or

$a…b  a … b  $
\end{document}
```

Their results seem to be similar.

[image]

Comment: Search for *ellipsis* and you will find a lot of discussion about this topic. Eg: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29840/consistent-typography or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30218/ellipsis-with-a-period-fullstop

Comment: @Reza: In the addendum you're provided to your original question, you purport to show that `...` and `\ldots` produce rather similar output (but with the dots apparently raised noticeably above the baseline). Which document class and which specialized packages did you load to create this output? Please consider posting a MWE (minimum working example) that generates the output you show.

Comment: @Mico I added a MWE to the question

Comment: Please note that (at least in german typography) there is a difference between `a…b` and `a … b`. In the first case the ellipsis shows that there is a part of a word missing and the latter case shows that one or more words, i.e. a part of the sentence (is), are missing …

Comment: Oh sure :-) But it won’t harm to hav this information as a comment :-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve advantages of both (readability and good appearance) using `Unicode Character 'HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS' (U+2026)`

If you have installed AutoHotKey use following script to convert `...` to `…` automatically:

```
::...::…
```

> In Windows, it can be inserted with Alt+0133.
>
> In MacOS, it can be inserted with ⌥ Opt+; (on an English language
>   keyboard).
>
> In Linux, it can be inserted with AltGr+.

Comment: This is definitely the nicest answer; it feels much saner than using some seemingly random thing, such as the stretchability of inter-word spacing, as the spacing between the dots.

Comment: With a german Mac keyboard use `opt`+`.` (dot) to get the ellipsis

Comment: This is definitely not the right way to do it. `\ldots` is the right way to do it.

Comment: Ditto @Nathaniel. `\ldots` should definitely be preferred over a unicode character.

Comment: the spacing of the dots depends heavily on the design of the font.  many fonts have the dots too close together for decent math typesetting.

Answer (score 105):

*Remark -- The answer given below addressed the original version of the posting, which asked if there's an advantage to using* `\ldots` *over* `...` *(three consecutive dots). At some later stage (May 2013?), the posting was changed to ask a* different *question, viz., what the best method is for inserting a text ellipsis in a (Xe)TeX document. The OP also provided a new answer at the time.*

---

You asked:

> Is there any advantage in using `\ldots` instead of `...`?

Yes! If you type `...` you'll get some rather-closely spaced dots. In contrast, with `\ldots` the dots are correctly spaced for a *typographic ellipsis*.

The following MWE illustrates some of the visual differences of what's outpot by `...` and `\ldots`. The differences are readily apparent in both text mode and math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
yes and no ... yes and no \ldots\ yes and no ...

$\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ vs.\ $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Naturally, if your language is not English -- for which `\ldots` was designed initially -- you'll want to make sure that the ellipis created by `\ldots` conforms to your language's typographic conventions. @egreg's comment suggests that this may well be a concern for the French case. For such situations, you may want to use the commands provided by a specialized package such as `ellipsis` or `csquotes` rather than the "standard" `\ldots` command.

*Addendum* prompted by a follow-up question by @moose: In LaTeX, there's also the command `\dots`. This raises the question, what is the difference between `\ldots` and `\dots`? The simple answer is: There's no difference in LaTeX. (I'm not sure if this applies to Plain TeX as well; I don't have the TeXbook at hand today...) The definitions of these two commands (from `latex.ltx`) are as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\dots}{%
   \ifmmode\mathellipsis\else\textellipsis\fi}
\let\ldots\dots
```

The `\textellipsis` instruction, in turn, is defined in the LaTeX kernel as follows:

```
\DeclareTextCommandDefault{\textellipsis}{%
    .\kern\fontdimen3\font
    .\kern\fontdimen3\font
    .\kern\fontdimen3\font}
```

Interestingly, there's no kern inserted ahead of the first `.` ("dot").

Comment: The correctess of the spacing between the dots depends on the typographic tradition; for instance in France they should be spaced much less than what `\ldots` provides.

Comment: @egreg I guess the point is that with `...` you get 'whatever', whereas _with appropriate set up_ `\ldots` will give the correct spacing.

Comment: @Mico could you please also explain the difference to `\dots`?

Comment: @moose: A good question. Please see the new addendum.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the answer! I've just found another one: `\cdots`. It could mean centered dots.

Comment: @moose -- `\cdots` is a math-mode ellipsis, for use between *binary* operators, as in $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n$. This ellipsis shouldn't be used in text-mode applications.

Comment: Can I simply always use `\dots` or does `\cdots` sometimes render different (better)?

Comment: @moose -- if you use the `amsmath` package, you could indeed always use `\dots` and let the package decide which ellipsis form is most appropriate in a given situation. Please read the package's user guide to learn more about this.

Answer (score 36):

I suggest using `\ldots` in combination with the package [ellipsis](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ellipsis), because that gives you better control over spacing than `...`. Using  `\ldots` alone (without `ellipsis`) is better than `...` because it gives you more flexibility. For example, you may redefine the spacing by redefining `\ldots`. On the other hand, `ellipsis` makes it easy to fine tune spacing, and takes care of other spacing problems, for example to combine ellipsis with full stop (....).

If you want to fine tune ellipsis, you easily change the distance between the dots by the command:

```
\renewcommand{\ellipsisgap}{0.1em} %  or another value
```

By adding the option `[xspace]`, *i.e.*

```
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
```

terminating the `\ldots`-command by `\` is not necessary (but even `xspace` makes errors, as documented in the manual). If you use `ellipsis`, remember to load it *after* `hyperref`.

The package [csquotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) has the commands

```
\textelp{}
\textelp{<text>}
\textelp*{<text>}
```

that fill similar functions as `ellipsis` and give you the tools for automatically handle exception from the rules. Therefore, they are better solutions than `...`.

I recommend using `\ldots` with `ellipsis` (or substitutes), which give best control over spacing, more flexibility and typographical consistency in more situations.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Sveinnung Your answer doesn't address the advantage issue.

Comment: Thanks. You actually explained an advantage, unfortunately I can just accept one answer :( Thanks again

Comment: @Sveinung Much better.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well with `\nonfrenchspacing`.