# What is the difference between \dots and \ldots?

Tags: macros, punctuation

Is there a difference between `\dots` and `\ldots`, the ellipsis?

If yes: Which? When to use `\dots` and when to use `\ldots`?

If no: Why are there both at all?

Comment: `\dots` is [magic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649/how-do-magic-dots-work-in-amsmath)! ... when using amsmath ;-)

Comment: A great answer is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73469/5645)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

in `latex.ltx`, `\ldots` is equated (`\let`) to `\dots`.  so in text, it's the same, and you can use either.

with [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), the situation is more complicated; `\dots` tries to determine by context (only in math mode) whether to use `\ldots` or `\cdots`, with several more options for the author if [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) doesn't get it right.

so in general, it's easier to just use `\dots` and not have to remember the details.  but if the alternative chosen by [`amsmath`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) isn't appropriate, the original commands can still be used explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I'm curious: Where or how to learn these things in the first place?

Comment: @FooBar `texdoc source2e` is a good starting point :)

Comment: @FooBar and for the ams `\dots` see `texdoc amsmath`, of course.

Comment: An example I just run into: I placed a \dots between two \cdot and promptly they landed on the same height as them. Methinks this looks awkward and I used \ldots, forcing them into basement. Your esthetic may vary.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann -- there *are* exceptions.  this is one of them.  it's always possible to override the `amsmath` decisions when necessary.

Comment: @Enderman -- I didn't reject the edit, but there was a distinct reason for not capitalizing anything.  At the time I wrote this answer, I was one of the TeX support staff at the American Math Society (AMS), and distinguished between "official" statements and ones that were my own opinion by capitalizing or not capitalizing.  This answer was not approved by the AMS; it was based on my own knowledge.  You have altered history.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, oops! Didn't realize that! Maybe put that comment in the answer? Sorry about that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Just fixed it.

Comment: @Enderman -- Thanks.