# What is the difference between ‎\ldots‎ and ‎\cdots‎?

Tags: amsmath

What is the difference between ‍‍`\ldots‎` and ‎`\cdots‎`?

For example, To write a sequence of points which is best to use?
`a_1,\ldots,a_n` Or `a_1,\cdots,a_n`.

Couple of examples of the difference can be useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\dots versus \ldots - is there a difference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77737/dots-versus-ldots-is-there-a-difference)

Comment: Load `amsmath` and use `\dots`; in the vast majority of cases, the result will be what's usually found in mathematical publications.

Comment: Please do not vote so soon to close a question.  The questioner should have the chance to respond to comments.  It is better to initially ask whether the potential duplicate answers their question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Although I agree with egreg's comment, the difference is mainly of an aesthetic nature imo.
It depends on the context which version to use, which is also how `amsmath` decides which to use.

Some examples:

`a_1,\ldots,a_n` aligns better than `a_1,\cdots,a_n`.

But `a_1 \to \ldots \to a_n` aligns worse than `a_1 \to \cdots \to a_n`.

The alignment chosen by amsmath is usually the one commonly found in mathematical articles. However, I guess its not really wrong or anything to deviate from it.

[image]

Comment: while some authors may deviate from the "usual" pattern, a copyeditor trained in math tradition will mark deviations except in very special cases.  `amsmath` was constructed to follow traditional typographic usage (which *is*, as noted, based largely on alignment, to avoid calling attention to its appearance and thus away from the underlying meaning).

Comment: I am told that the standard practice is to use `\ldots` when the separator symbol is bottom-aligned (eg: comma ) and to use `\cdots` when the separator symbol is at center-aligned (eg: `\to`)

Comment: @CyriacAntony that is **exactly** what I use `\ldots` and `\cdots` for.

Comment: I back this suggestion; https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77742/157031 (already pointed out by egreg in comment to the question)

Answer (score 0):

Idots are used between the comma's (at the bottom) where as cdots are used between mostly in plus minus signs (at the middle of the line).

Comment: Why is this answer down voted?

Comment: Good question, I don't know why it was downvoted either! Lemme upvote it to balance it out a bit :)