# Comprehensive list of mathmode dots with explanations

Tags: math-mode, punctuation

I have read [on](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77737/dots-versus-ldots-is-there-a-difference) [several](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117730/what-is-the-difference-between-ldots-and-cdots) [occasions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649/how-do-magic-dots-work-in-amsmath) that there are differences between the multitude of `dots` commands that TeX and `amsmath` offer. However, I am not sure up to this day when to use which, and how critical it really is whether I use the correct one or not.

The document [`mathmode`](http://ftp.cis.nctu.edu.tw/CTAN/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf) by Herbert Voss points out:

> It is not easy to see the differences between some of them.

That obviously does not help me any further.

Could you provide some explanation for each of the commands, and in which context to use them for the rest of us? Further, some example explaining how big the difference between the commands really is would be great.

Comment: NB: There seems to be an error in `CTAN`. Although it lists mathmode.pdf as v 2.47, it links to the outdated v 2.32.

See http://www.ctan.org/pkg/voss-mathmode .

Comment: Where is the sense to link a _CTAN_ document to another location than CTAN itself??? http://mirror.ctan.org/info/math/voss/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf is a correct link. However, if it points to 2.32 then the mirror is out of date, which is _not_ a problem of CTAN. Everybody gets the document with `texdoc Mathmode`

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Dots

Comment: some information is given in [\dots versus \ldots - is there a difference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77737/579).  more details, with brief examples, can be found in section 4.3, p.9, of the `amsmath` users guide, `texdoc amsmath`.

Comment: @Herbert -- the version of `Mathmode.pdf` on ctan really is out of date.  tex live 2012 had version 2.47, but it (tex live) reverted to 2.32 in 2013.  i've written to you off-line about this.