# When to use \dots, \ldots, \cdots, and blanks?

Tags: punctuation

I am writing math. questions like these:

- Complete the missing numbers: 3,4,...,...,7
- 5+...=7
- The rectangle contains four ... angles (choices: acute, obtuse or right)

In each case of the mentioned ones, which is the suitable to use? (dots - ldots - cdots - a blank)

Comment: `\dots` is an amsmath macro that tries to automate the choice between ldots and cdots (by looking at the following symbol mostly)

Comment: relevant, though not duplicates: [\dots versus \ldots - is there a difference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77737/579) and [Difference of the \dots*](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122491/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The first asks "when to use `\dots` and/or `\ldots`"... for me a clear duplicate.

Comment: @werner -- to some extent i agree, but it doesn't cover `\cdots`, which is why i referred to the second question as well.

Comment: The referred questions are neglecting the issue of when to use it specifically. So, i need more clarification and i put these examples to get your help.

Comment: @AymanOsama: Note that such a question (in general) could be considered opinion-based. Where I like the look of `\cdots`, others may feel `\ldots` are sufficient.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The topic of this question isn't really when to use which `\*dot*`, but rather how to typeset the kind of exercises that OP showed. Only the title is very misleading.

Comment: Please suggest a new title and i can change it. I hope also to find a clear answer to the question.

Comment: @Werner I don't think it's an opinion-based question. I am sure there is a rule to differentiate between dots between numbers in a series and numbers between operators, and other types of dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMS offers several dot (ellipsis) styles, use the one matching your intent:

- `\dotsc`: For use between commas, e.g `a, b, \dotsc, z`
- `\dotsb`: To elide binary operators, like `a_n z^n + a_{n - 1} z^{n - 1} + \dotsb + a_0`
- `\dotsm`: Ditto, multiplications, as in `n! = n \cdot (n - 1) \dotsm 1`

There is also a set for use in arrays (matrices).

In general, I've found that the extra work to select the precise alternative instead of hoping LaTeX will Always Do The Right Thing is minimal, and pays off in better results (as said LaTeX selection is based on very limited information).

Answer (score 4):

Since what you try to do is like a cloze text, consider using underlines. This is (from what I recall) what a cloze text should have.

You could do it like this

```
The rectangle contains \underline{\;\phantom{right}\;} angles.
```

producing

[image: Result of the above command.]

This will work in maths environment, as well. I added `\;` for some extra spacing.