# How can I write underneath the equation "b+b+...+b" n-times?

Tags: equations

I am new to LaTex, I am using a Overleaf. I'm trying to write the equation

```
n\times b= b+b+...+b
```

with '`n-times`' in the bottom.

Comment: Off-topic: There's no need for the hyphen character between "n" and "times". Just write `n \text{times}` and you'll be fine.

Comment: Doesn't merely "n" suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    n\times b=\underbrace{b+b+\cdots+b}_{n\textup{-times}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You might replace `\cdots` with `\ldots`. See also [When to use \dots, \ldots, \cdots, and blanks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274443/when-to-use-dots-ldots-cdots-and-blanks) and [\dots versus \ldots - is there a difference?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77737/dots-versus-ldots-is-there-a-difference). Please read Mico's comment.

[image]

Comment: @JouleV I am sorry, I do not see that `\cdots` does not correspond to the posted image.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
$n \times b=\underbrace{b+b+\ldots+b}_{n}$
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```