# How to properly space unicode ellipsis?

Tags: formatting, unicode, ellipsis

Please note the discussion at the end of [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73467/what-is-best-method-to-insert-an-ellipsis-in-a-xetex-document). After discussing the tex codes \ldots et al, a commenter points out that there is a unicode code point for an ellipsis.

However, on my document (which I'm editing in Lyx), the `…` character prints out in my pdf as something resembling a `\cdots` code; that is, vertically centered (and in my case, also shifted horizontally to collide with the next word after the whitespace). See the graphic:

[image: cropped output of a text sample. The raw text is "lines of … cultural exchange"]

In the pdf file itself, I can copy the ellipsis out, and when I paste it into another document, it remains an ellipsis.

This is undesireable behavior; how do I tell TeX to treat the unicode ellipsis correctly as a baseline ellipsis character, and format it accordingly?

ETA: here is an mwe, which isolates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\newfontfamily\zhcn [Path=/usr/share/fonts/arphicfonts/]{uming}
\begin{document}
blah … ... blah
\end{document}
```

On my system, that outputs the ellipsis character as raised and shifted rightwards. If I drop those two lines from the preamble, the text is correctly formatted.
But the xeCJK package shouldn't be called unless I specifically flag something to use it, right?

Comment: Could we have a `minimal working example`?

Comment: For its working (I don't know exactly why), `xeCJK` assigns `…` (U+2026) to character class 3; it also defines interchar tokens between classes 0 (default) and 3, with the result that the character `…` is taken from the main CJK font.