# Best symbol to use for ... in the case of 1,...,n

Tags: symbols

What symbol do people find gives best results for ... where this is in the case 1,...,n?

Comment: Load `amsmath` package and use `\dots`. If you use it for a sum, for example, it will be lifted a little bit.

Comment: See [`\dots` versus `\ldots` - is there a difference?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77737/5764)

Comment: ...also see [What is best method to insert an ellipsis in a (Xe)TeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73467/5764).

Comment: also [Difference of the `\dots*`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122491/difference-of-the-dots)