# Is renaming \dots as \ellipsis or \etc semantic overkill?

Tags: amsmath, semantics, ellipsis

In the Wikibook about LaTeX's [section on dots](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Dots), it's suggested that "Instead of using `\ldots` and `\cdots`, you should use the semantically oriented commands." The author then goes on to list `amsmath`'s semantically oriented `\dots` commands: `\dotsc`, `\dotsb`, etc., which respectively stand for "dots with commas", "dots with binary operators/relations", etc.

But I was just thinking that if we wanted to be *really* semantically oriented, since when we write `\dots` what we actually mean is "ellipsis" or "et cetera", perhaps we should define a collection of `\ellipsis` commands like:

```
\newcommand*{\ellipsis}{\dots}
\newcommand*{\ellipsisc}{\dotsc} % "ellipsis with commas"
\newcommand*{\ellipsisb}{\dotsb} % "ellipsis with binary operators/relations"
etc.
```

or, since those commands were getting rather long, we could instead define a collection of `\etc` commands like:

```
\newcommand*{\etc}{\dots}
\newcommand*{\etcc}{\dotsc} % "et cetera with commas"
\newcommand*{\etcb}{\dotsb} % "et cetera with binary operators/relations"
etc.
```

While I find this quite satisfying with regards to being semantically sound, I worry that defining all of these new commands amounts to semantic overkill since I haven't seen anyone else rename the `\dots` commands. Am I taking semantic orientation too far?

Comment: The amsmath dots have different spacing, it is not just semantics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason semantic naming is recommended in LaTeX is to prevent you from doing too much work if you go back and change the definition. For example, to highlight definitions, I have `\newcommand{\term}{\emph}`, so I can use `\term` to indicate where I define a new word. But if I want to change definitions to be bold instead of emphasized, I could simply update the command once, rather than having to comb through my whole document.

Thus, you should ask yourself: is there any chance you would use something other than `\dots`, `\dotsc`, and `\dotsb` for ellipses? If so, make a new command, but if not, there's no reason to.

A little more information on ellipses that may help: [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29845/55879) [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73467/what-is-best-method-to-insert-an-ellipsis-in-a-xetex-document).

Comment: I see; do you mean to ask if there's any chance I would use `\dots`, `\dotsc`, and `\dotsb` for anything other than ellipses?

Comment: No, sorry, the opposite: is there a chance that you might want to define `\ellipsis` to be something else later? Or will you always want `\dots` when you need an ellipsis? (Same thing for `\ellipsisc` and `\dotsc`, etc.)