# What is the difference in citing/referencing with or without tilde?

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing, citing, syntax

I've seen examples referencing a table as follows:

`Table~\ref{table:overview} shows an overview of all the elements.`

What is the use of the tilde in front of `\ref` or `\cite` and when do you have to apply it?

Comment: Also see [Consistent typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).

Comment: For a brief (0.5 pages) overview of spaces (normal space, `~`, `\ `, `\@`), see section 2.6 of [The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).

Answer (score 131, accepted):

The tilde `~` is an unbreakable space, i.e. the line will never be broken at this position. If you write `Table~\ref{...}` the table number generated by `\ref` will always be on the same line as `Table`, which is the preferable formatting. Having "Table" at the end of a line and then "1" at the beginning of the next simply looks bad.

The tilde is also used in names if they include a title, like `Dr.~Faust`, which will also ensure that the "Dr." and the name is not broken between two lines, *and also* ensures that the `.` is not taken as a full-stop, which usually produces a larger space after it.

Comment: The larger space is produced in English documents; if you use `babel` e.g. with the `ngerman` option, a sentence-final period won't be followed by an enlarged space.

Comment: Should we use tilde before `\cite{}` too?

Answer (score 32):

From the TeX Book (**Chapter 6: Running TeX**, p 25):

> [The `~` signs] are called *ties*, because they tie words together;
>   i.e., TeX is supposed to treat `~` as a normal space but not to break
>   between lines there. A good typist will use ties within names, as
>   shown in our example; further discussion of ties appears in
>   Chapter 14.

Continued in **Chapter 14: How TeX Breaks Paragraphs into Lines**, p 91-93:

> "Ties" - denoted by `~` in plain TeX - are the key to successful line
>   breaking. Once you learn how to insert them, you will have graduated
>   from the ranks of ordinary TeXnical typists to the select group of
>   Distinguished TeXnicians. And it's really not difficult to train
>   yourself to insert occasional ties, almost without thinking, as you
>   type a manuscript.
>
> When you type `~` it's the same as typing a space, except that TeX
>   won't break a line at this space. Furthermore, you shouldn't leave any
>   blanks next to the `~`, since they will count as additional spaces. If
>   you put `~` at the very end of a line in your input file, you'll get a
>   wider space than you want, because the `<return>` that follows the `~`
>   produces an extra space.
>
> We have already observed in Chapter 12 that it's generally a good
>   idea to type `~` after an abbreviation that does not come at the end
>   of a sentence. Ties also belong in several other places:
>
> - In references to named parts of a document:
>
>   `Chapter~12` & `Theorem~1.2`    `Appendix~A` & `Table~\hbox{B-8}`
>     `Figure~3` & `Lemmas 5 and~6`
>
>   No `~` appears after `Lemmas` in the final example, since there's no
>     harm in having `5~and~6` at the beginning of a line. The use of
>     `\hbox` is explained below.
> - Between a person's forenames and between multiple surnames:
>
>   `Donald~E. Knuth` & `Luis~I. Trabb~Pardo`
>     `Bartel~Leendert
>     van~der~Waerden` & `Charles~XII`
>
>   Note that it is sometimes better to hyphenate a name than to break it
>     between words; e.g., `Don-` and `ald~E.~Knuth` is more tolerable than
>     `Donald` and `E.~Knuth`. The previous rule can be regarded as a
>     special case of this one, since we may think of `Chapter~12` as a
>     compound name; another example is `register~X`. Sometimes a name is so
>     long that we dare not tie it all together, lest there be no way to
>     break the line:
>
>   `Charles Louis Xavier~Joseph de~la Vall\'ee~Poussin.`
> - Between math symbols in apposition with nouns:
>
>   `dimension~$d$`   `width~$w$`   `function~$f(x)$`
>     `string~$s$ of length~$l$`
>
>   However, the last example should be compared with
>
>   `string~$s$ of length $l$~or more.`
> - Between symbols in series:
>
>   `1,~2, or~3`
>     `$a$,~$b$, and~$c$.`
>     `1,~2, \dots,~$n$.`
> - When a symbol is a tightly bound object of a preposition:
>
>   `of~$x$`
>     `from 0 to~1`
>     `increase $z$ by~1`
>     `in common with~$m$.`
>
>   The rule does not, however, apply to compound objects:
>
>   `of $u$~and~$v$.`
> - When mathematical phrases are rendered in words:
>
>   `equals~$n$` & `less than~$\epsilon$` & `(given~$X$)`
>     `mod~2` & `modulo~$p^e$` & `for all large~$n$`
>
>   Compare `is~15` with `is 15~times the height`.
> - When cases are being enumerated within a paragraph:
>
>   `(b)~Show that $f(x)$ is (1)~continuous; (2)~bounded.`
>
>   It would be nice to boil all of these rules down to one or two simple
>     principles, and it would be even nicer if the rules could be
>     automated so that keyboarding could be done without them; but subtle
>     semantic considerations seem to be involved. Therefore it's best to
>     use your own judgment with respect to ties. The computer needs your
>     help.
>
> A tie keeps TeX from breaking at a space, but sometimes you want to
>   prevent the machine from breaking at a hyphen or a dash. This can be
>   done by using `\hbox`, because TeX will not split up the contents of a
>   box; boxes are indecomposable units, once they have been constructed. 
>   We have already illustrated this principle in the `Table~\hbox{B-8}`
>   example considered earlier.  Another example occurs when you are
>   typing the page numbers in a bibliographic reference: It doesn't look
>   good to put `22.` on a line by itself, so you can type
>   `\hbox{13--22}.` to prohibit breaking `13--22.` On the other hand, TeX
>   doesn't often choose line breaks at hyphens, so you needn't bother to
>   insert `\hbox` commands unless you need to correct a bad break that
>   TeX has already made on a previous run.

Comment: I think these recommendations, while sensible, have caused a too restrictive view among LaTeXers regarding style. For example, the Chicago Manual of Style writes "the squishing or stretching of text that results from the use of nonbreaking spaces can be even more unsightly [than what the OP there is asking about]" in their [online Q&A](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Documentation/faq0193.html) (Note: When CMOS discusses page numbers there, they aren't preceded by "p." in the context of their question; but their general sentiment against overdoing it still holds.)

Comment: You write `Lemmas 5 and~6` as an example, but then include the explanation: No `~` appears after `Lemmas` in the final example, since there's no harm in having `5~and~6` at the beginning of a line. I suspect a missing `~` after the first `5`?

Comment: @justin I think the point here is that normally it would be bad if it said "Lemma" at the end of a line and "5" on the next line. When there is more than one part, however, it is not a problem to have "Lemmas 5" on one line, and "and 6" on the next. Therefore there is no missing "~" between "Lemmas" and "5". The "~" in "and~6" should be there, of course, to avoid breaking between "and" and "6".

Comment: @LoverofStructure: Sure, too many ties can cause line-breaking issues, but as long as you proofread your document, it's better to insert too many ties on your first pass than too few. It's way easier to spot terrible spacing and remove ties as necessary than it is to see semantically poor line breaks and *add* ties at proof time.

Answer (score 14):

the tilde is used to keep the table number (or other reference) from breaking to a new line during the justification process.  it's especially nice to avoid this breaking when the cited reference is the last thing in a paragraph.