# ~\cite adds space between citation and text

Tags: spacing, citing

I am trying to add citations to a technical report using `~\cite`, so that the result would be `text[1]`. But instead I get `text [1]` with a space between the citation and the text. I am using `\usepackage{cite}`. How do I remove the space?

Comment: Why would you remove the space?

Comment: Requirement of the report.

Comment: I always keep forgetting that crazy requirements are so frequent. :(

Comment: Thank god there are still people telling us that we should not want what we want. We would be the eternal slaves of our stupid wishes. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

To remove the space, remove the tilde `~` and just use `text\cite{...}`. This is, however, a rather unusual use of `\cite`.

In short, when you type `~` (also called a "tie") it's the same as typing a space, except that TeX won't break a line at this space. For a reference on the usage of `~` with/without citation, see [What is the difference in citing/referencing with or without tilde?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41264/5764)

Comment: Removing the tilde doesn't remove the space.

Comment: @user1049697: Did you use `...text \cite{..}` or `...text\cite{..}`? If *neither* of these work, then you should post a minimal example as part of your question showing exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 5):

You can add an option for the [`cite`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cite) package:

```
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}
```

to avoid the unwanted space .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.