# Acceptable use cases for xspace; When will it fail?

Tags: spacing, macros, xspace

I have used `xspace` for a long time to take care of adding space after usage of some macros.  Usually, it is with a macro to format a word consistently, as in:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\matlab}{\textsc{matlab}\xspace}
\newcommand{\enterprise}{\emph{USS Enterprise\nocorr}\xspace}
For me, \matlab is the best; I like to program in \matlab.

The \enterprise was a famous ship.
\end{document}
```

In a [recent question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176390), I made the comment that

> *The `xspace` package is very nice to avoid the need for `{}` at every use of a macro defined in such a manner.*

It was replied to me that

> *Many people say so, but the author of xspace isn't so sure:*
>   [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace)

The conclusion at the referenced post is "if you find it useful, fine, it's there. But personally I *[David Carlisle, original author of `xspace`]* wouldn't recommend it."

Yet, [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106727) not too long after by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) seems to use `xspace` without hesitation, recommending it implicitly in the use of simple macros, e.g.:

```
\usepackage{xspace}

\newcommand{\Poincare}{Poincar\'e\xspace}
\newcommand{\adele}{ad\`ele\xspace}
\newcommand{\Cech}{\v{C}ech\xspace}
\newcommand{\Erdos}{Erd\H{o}s\xspace}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\etale}{\'etal\@ifstar{\'e}{e\xspace}}
\makeatother
```

So, my questions come down to these three:

1. Are there any acceptable (non-controversial) use cases for `xspace`? (perhaps the case as shown above from egreg, similar to my original example?)
2. What types of cases might the use of `xspace` actually cause problems?  (Is it just things like the italic correction of the `\enterprise` example above?)
3. If problems in spacing are caused via a macro, will `xspace` fail in the same way with every use of that macro, or will it be dependent on the context where the macro is used?

Comment: I'm not a fan of `\xspace`, but for those commands, which are likely to appear just in “quiet” places, it can be employed. The case of `\emph{\Poincare}` (where `\xspace` could fail to add the italic correction) might have been mentioned.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I comment in the referenced answer, part of the problem with `xspace` is that it's not entirely trivial to answer *this* question. That is xpsace fails when it fails and it isn't so easy to give a useful summary of exactly when that is.

xspace has to look ahead to decide whether to add a space or not. Basically it doesn't add space if it sees punctuation. But the macro seeing punctuation and punctuation appearing in the typeset result isn't the same thing.

so

```
\xspace,
```

the `,` is detected and no space is added.

```
\xspace\mbox{,}
```

The `,' isn't detected.

Now probably you don't type that in your document, but if you are using a babel shortcut for language sensitive punctuation, or a package for smart quotes or any one of a thousand other possibilities, then the effective result may be similar.

So basically `\xspace` works if the arbitrary tokens that follow the macro that ends with `\xspace` are defined in a way that allows `\xspace` to see any characters that ought to suppress the space.