# Why doesn't \xspace always insert a following space when that is expected?

Tags: macros, xspace

In the MWE, `\xspace` correctly inserts a space in the first test of `\foo`, but not in the second test when it is followed by an en-dash.

Is there a fix for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO\xspace}

\begin{document}
\foo BAR

\foo -- why no space here?

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Note the question is misworded, `xspace` _never_ detects the space, the space is not available to tex macros at all.  so it detects `B` in the first case  and `-` in the second. for `B` it guesses a space is needed so adds one, for `-` it guesses it is a hyphenated word, so does not.  The input `\foo --` is identical to the input `\foo--` after tex parsing, neither generates a space token.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Question tItle edited!

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180686/acceptable-use-cases-for-xspace-when-will-it-fail/180714#180714

Answer (score 16):

The hyphen character `-` is in `xspace`'s exception list<sup>1</sup>, where the space isn't added. You can remove it with `\xspaceremoveexception{-}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO\xspace}

\begin{document}
\foo BAR

\foo -- why no space here?

\xspaceremoveexception{-}
\foo -- why no space here?

\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

As David said in the comments, **`xspace` doesn't detect the space**. As far as it knows `\foo--bar` and `\foo --bar` are *exactly* the same, because at the time `\xspace` gets to do its thing, TeX has already tokenized the macro and the next character, and any space in between was ignored.

`xspace` looks ahead to see if the next character is supposed to be preceded by a space and *re*-inserts that space if it is needed.

With the solution above, we changed `\xspace`'s exception list, so it will *always*, from now on, add a space before a `-`, even when you don't want it to.

#### Still not satisfied?

If you want to hack into `\xspace`'s rules, you can start by the example given in the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO\xspace}

\begin{document}
\foo BAR

\foo -- why no space here?

\xspaceremoveexception{-}
\foo -- why no space here?

\xspaceremoveexception{-}% repeated, for the sake of copy-pasting
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@xspace@hook{%
  \ifx\@let@token-%
    \expandafter\@xspace@dash@i
  \fi
}
\def\@xspace@dash@i-{\futurelet\@let@token\@xspace@dash@ii}
\def\@xspace@dash@ii{%
  \ifx\@let@token-%
  \else
    \unskip
  \fi
  -%
}
\makeatother

\foo - why no space here?

\foo -- why no space here?

\end{document}
```

> [image]

There David shows how to use `\@xspace@hook` to check if the next *two* characters are `--` and, if not, remove the space inserted by `\xspace`. This can be expanded to check more characters<sup>2</sup>, but is it worth it?

My 2 cents: I used `xspace` for a few months, when I was writing my bachelor's thesis. It helps you not forget to type `\foo{}` or `\foo\` when you are in the habit of forgetting it. But with time, you need different things (as you did here), and it gets more time consuming than it should. My opinion (and David's, apparently :P).

---

<sup>1</sup> The exception list, by default, contains:

```
,.'/?;:!~-)\ \/\bgroup\egroup\@sptoken\space\@xobeysp\footnote\footnotemark
%        ↑ Here it is :)
```

<sup>2</sup> Apparently I've got nothing better to do :)

The `\@xspace@hook` below checks:

1. If what follows `\foo` is a single `-`. If it is, it removes the space inserted by `\xspace` and returns;
2. If what follows `\foo` is `--`. If it is, it looks ahead for a space. If the space is found, the space inserted by `\xspace` is kept, otherwise it is removed. That is:

   ```
   \foo-bar  % prints FOO-bar
   \foo-- bar% prints FOO -- bar
   \foo--bar % prints FOO--bar
   ```

(note that either way, the space after `\foo` does not matter because of TeX's parsing rules).

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\foo}{FOO\xspace}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\foo BAR

\foo -- why no space here?

\xspaceremoveexception{-}
\foo -- why no space here?

\xspaceremoveexception{-}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@xspace@hook{%
  \begingroup
  \ifx\@let@token-%
    \obeyspaces
    \expandafter\@xspace@dash@i
  \fi
}
\def\@xspace@dash@i-{\futurelet\@let@token\@xspace@dash@ii}
\def\@xspace@dash@ii{%
  \ifx\@let@token-%
    \expandafter\@xspace@dash@sp@i
  \else
    \unskip
    -%
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\def\@xspace@dash@sp@i-{\futurelet\@let@token\@xspace@dash@sp@ii}
\def\@xspace@dash@sp@ii{%
  \ifx\@let@token\space%
  \else
    \unskip
  \fi
  --%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\foo - why no space here?

\foo -- why no space here?

\foo--why no space here?

\end{document}
```

Comment: all true but you could also make clear that xspace never detects the space after `\foo` so if you do this `\foo--BAR` would also make `FOO --BAR` with a space being _inserted_ by xspace.

Comment: But removing `-` from the exception list messes up using a single `-` as a hyphen character. Oh well, I suppose I can't have *everything* working the way I want it ;)

Comment: @alephzero my recommendation would be to not use xspace at all https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620

Comment: OK, I'll consider throwing `\newcommand` away as well, and using `\def\foo/{FOO}` with a guard character to prevent accidents. (`\foo --` is now invalid, but `\foo/--` and `\foo/ --` both do what you would expect.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Done. Slightly wordier version :)

Comment: @alephzero See my edit. It takes some time to get used to TeX's space ignoring rules, but eventually you learn them (not that I have). For some time I also adopted the `\foo/` technique. It's more manageable than using `xspace`, but eventually I got back to using `\foo{}` (can't remember what made me abandon `\foo/` though :P)