# Why not using xspace

Tags: xspace

I often read that one should not use `xspace` package, but why? Can someone give an example of problems caused?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620/2388

Comment: actually this a better duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/180686/acceptable-use-cases-for-xspace-when-will-it-fail/180714#180714