# Macro processor tries too hard without curly braces

Tags: macros

Given this MWE;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\ee{\=e\=e}

\begin{document}
    sh\ee{n}g ur k\=asn
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to eliminate the curly braces that prevent the macro processor from becoming confused and looking for another macro name? Similar to the way that `\=a` does not consume the following s. I have just now noticed that the `\ee` will consume the following space for reasons I do not have sufficient LaTeX-Fu to correct other than with a pair of closed braces `{}.`

Comment: Will someone with the power move this to regular TeX?

Comment: @CarLaTex Am I correct in thinking that there is no ability to move questions to the correct place?

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks!

Comment: Is the problem that you don't want to type `{n}` and instead would prefer to type just `n`? That is the exact reason why the following space is consumed, it allows you to type `\ee n` and that will give the same output as `\ee{n}`.

Comment: @Marijn Exactly! I have many of these double-letter additions, and the slight annoyance adds up. Besides, it would be nice to add this ability to my macro writing.

Comment: Take a look at these two earlier questions: [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091) and [Acceptable use cases for xspace; When will it fail?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/180686)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, these solve the mystery of the macro that ate a space! Thanks for the pointer…

Comment: @barbarabeeton, well I don't need the empty braces anymore, so that part is solved. But the larger problem of having to enclose a letter that follows such a macro with braces still remains.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but ending the definition with empty braces would mean that the last `\=e` is "blocked": `\def\ee{\=e\=e{}}`.  By the way, since you're using LaTeX and not plain, you'll be better off in the long run to use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`; if a command name already exists, `\newcommand` will check, and complain if it does; `\def` will happily overwrite it, and may surprise you later.

Comment: @hsmyers I have to admit I still don't fully understand what exactly the problem is. Do you want to be able to type `\een` with the result of running `\ee` and then printing `n`? This would be rather different from how programming languages normally work, it would be quite difficult to implement and it could introduce confusion (what if you have defined both `\ee` and `\een`, which one should be taken?). Or is this not what you mean and you want something else? If so, what is the input syntax you want to use and what is the output that you expect from that?

Comment: @Marijn, what you have deduced is correct. I inquired, knowing it might be impossible and impractical. This is used frequently in phonetic spelling and is not subject to extension by adding a letter; the chance that someone else might have exists, but it seems a bit of a stretch to me.

Comment: Why not just typing `ēē`? With my keyboard its “option-a e”.

Comment: @egreg, what OS and what keyboard? I'm Windows with a nice but non-programable keyboard (i.e., non-gamers.)

Comment: @hsmyers I'm pretty sure there are dead keys also on Windows, but I can't test as Windows machines refuse to work when I'm in front of them (not only I, actually). The keyboard I use is the standard internetional keyboard on a Mac.

Comment: @egreg Well, if I translate "option" to control, then control a selects all of the text in the file, so problems abound. Be nice, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with LuaLaTeX. You can add a callback that post-processes each line to replace instances of `\ee` by `\ee` , i.e., add a space. `gsub` is a global replacement, so all occurrences in a line will be replaced. You can add other macros with additional `gsub` lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{luacode}

\def\ee{\=e\=e}
\def\oo{\=o\=o}

\begin{luacode}
    function addspace(line)
        line = string.gsub(line, "\\ee", "\\ee ")
        line = string.gsub(line, "\\oo", "\\oo ")
        return line
    end
    luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", addspace, "easytyping")
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
    sh\eeng ur k\=asn \oong \eeng
\end{document}
```

But I would recommend just typing `sh\ee ng ur k\=asn \oo ng \ee ng` yourself, it is very easy to get used to and it would save the trouble of doing the postprocessing.

Comment: So remove the \xspace in the macro and use the eating space in my favor? This from a macro version you've not seen.

Comment: There are two more macros. Does Lua have a case construct? Likewise, there are cases where the following character is a closing brace—which might be handled by the existing sub?

Comment: I've determined that this works well for the edge cases. All that I need is to add the else if statements, which, at a guess, would require knowing which macro I was looking at?

Comment: Of course one mustn't have the macros `\eel` or `\eek`, unless many more cases have to be added.

Comment: @egreg, Chuckle—seems unlikely in text involving Scottish Gaelic!

Comment: Another problem occurs to me: there is possibly more than one occurrence of these macros on a given line.

Comment: I'm going with your suggestion just use a space to separate as needed. In the edge case where they end with 'real' space, I'll just use a '~.'

Comment: @hsmyers I made two extensions to cover multiple macros and multiple occurrences of a single macro, just as a proof of principle.