# Using "\ " instead of "{}" after a macro

Tags: spacing

Given a macro definition like `\newcommand{\answer}{\emph{42}}`, do

```
They realized that \answer{} is the answer to everything.
```

and

```
They realized that \answer\ is the answer to everything.
```

always produce the same output?

Comment: you might consider something entirely different, such as `\newcommand{\answer}{\emph{42}\xspace}`.  see [Macros for common abbreviations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15009/579)

Comment: While `\xspace` might have some merits, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace

Comment: Related (duplicate?) [When to use \, { } or ~ to prohibit gobbling of a space following a macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62028)

Comment: The output may be different if `\nonfrenchspacing` is in force and the replacement text of the macro ends with a period (or other punctuation), because ``\ `` always inserts a normal (non sentence ending) space.

Comment: yet another possibility is to enter it as `... {\answer} ...`; this is "neutral" regarding frenchspacing, and doesn't have the disadvantages of `\xspace` pointed out by egreg.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: But `\answer\` ist more convenient to type for me.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! So, if I make sure I don't use punctation, I'm fine?

Comment: @felix-freiberger Yes. On the other hand, the German module for `babel` issues `frenchspacing`, so the problem disappears when writing in German.

Comment: @egreg OK, thank you! Unluckily, I can't accept a comment, so if you'd like to post that as an answer...

Comment: @felix-freiberger Would you be happy with closing this as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62028? If not, you should expand your question to make it different from the other one.

Comment: That question doesn't have an answer giving me a clear "Yes, they are equal, as long as...", just some cases where `~` behaves differently. Apart from that, this really is a duplicate.