# Reference a picture

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, line-breaking

I am writing a PhD thesis. Sometimes when I reference to a figure the following problem occurs. In PDF the word Fig.[number of figure] are written in two lines (Fig. and [] are separated). How to write the code that it will not be separated.

my code for figure:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{(4)13.png}
\caption{The dielectric permittivity bla bla bla.}
\label{(4)13}
\end {figure}
```

in text it is like

```
At the end of this chapter let us compare the numerical results for the phase mode frequency and dielectric response with experimental results. Fig. \ref{(4)13} shows the relaxation frequency ($\omega$) bla bla bla...
```

And in the PDF looks like:

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Best regards, Kristina

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a situation where you can use a `~`, which indicates a non-breaking space. I.e. `Fig.~\ref{abc}`.

Comment: See also [Why should I put a ~ before \ref or \cite?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9633) and [What is the difference in citing/referencing with or without tilde?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41264)

Comment: also just as a hint: you will at some point hate yourself for naming your files (4)13.png (which seems to be fig (4)17 already)

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I did not find those links and comments before. I see that it was quite trivial question. I spent all afternoon to solve the problem :)