# How do I break authors into groups with authblk?

Tags: titles, author, authblk

I have a paper that has a large number of authors, some of whom are primary and some of whom are secondary.  I am using the `authblk` package to handle the many affiliations like so:

```
\author[1]{Fred Foo}
\author[2]{Barbara Bar}
% Here I would like a line break
\author[1]{Sylvia Sub-Author}
...
```

According to the `authblk` package documentation

> if the author text is to be forced to a new line,
> use `\authorcr` ...

But it seems like that can only be used *within* an `\author` command's argument, not *between* author commands.
If I try to put `\authorcr` between the two authors in the example above, I get

```
A \newline or \\ command appears between paragraphs, where it makes no
sense. If you're trying to ``leave a blank line'', use a \vspace
command.
```

I can't actually use `\vspace` because the vertical space would appear in the document when the `\author` commands are being read, instead of when the `\maketitle` is executed.

I've tried putting a null author in, but that gives me an extra "," floating around.

Any suggestions?  This seems like something that users writing papers with lots of authors would often want to do.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} %DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{authblk}            % large number of authors

 \begin{document}




\title{Paper Concerning Something Very Interesting}
\author[1]{A.N. Author}
\author[4]{A.N. Other}
\author[2]{Y.A.N. Other}
\author[1]{A.N. Author, Jr.}
\author[2]{A.N. Author, III}
\author[1]{One Subordinate Author}
\author[3]{Two Subordinate Author}
\author[4]{Third Subordinate Author}
\author[5]{Fourth Subordinate Author}
\affil[1]{A Company}
\affil[2]{Another Company}
\affil[3]{YA Company}
\affil[4]{A University}
\affil[5]{Another University}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{abstract}
Yes, it's very abstract...
\end{abstract}


\begin{center}
  \Large \textit{Draft: Do not circulate}
\end{center}


\section{Introduction}

lorem ipsum

\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Gives this:
[image: Formatted MWE]

I would like to be able to put a break between "A.N. Author, III" and "One Subordinate Author."

Comment: Can you mock up a *complete*, minimal example? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` and allow us to copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're currently seeing. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner added MWE

Comment: Thanks! As reference, consider viewing [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) For example, since your problem resides with titles, there's no need for including `gensymb`, `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `xcolor`, ... since with their removal your working example should still function. Nor do you need all the margin and page settings, since they do not pertain to the problem. In short, remove all the content that doesn't pertain to the problem yet still allows to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Werner I have removed the extraneous materials, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A dirty but working hack is to add `\authorcr` inside the first `\author` after the desired line break:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{authblk}

\title{Paper Concerning Something Very Interesting}
\author[1]{A.N.~Author}
\author[4]{A.N.~Other}
% The \authorcr within the following \author forces a line break here
\author[2]{\authorcr Y.A.N.~Other}
\author[1]{A.N.~Author,~Jr.}
\author[2]{A.N.~Author,~III}
\author[1]{One~Subordinate~Author}
\author[3]{Two~Subordinate~Author}
\author[4]{Third~Subordinate~Author}
\author[5]{Fourth~Subordinate~Author}
\affil[1]{A~Company}
\affil[2]{Another~Company}
\affil[3]{YA~Company}
\affil[4]{A~University}
\affil[5]{Another~University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Note that it's also a good idea to use non-breaking spaces `~` in the author names [to avoid line breaks after the first name and the ensure proper spacing after a `.`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41268/61094).

[image]