# Resume numbering the footnote

Tags: numbering, footnotes

I use the following piece of code to put something as my footnote (borrowed from a friend).

```
{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext <text> }
```

But what happens is after putting this, any further footnote will not have numbering with it. I was wondering how to resume the numbering. I believe `\relax` is the culprit here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must be missing some group definition in your example, since

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Here is some text\footnote{First footnote}\par
Here is some text{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{Second footnote}}\par
Here is some text\footnote{Last footnote}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

The use of braces around the redefinition of `\thefootnote` - called scoping or grouping - makes ordinary modifications to macros only survive *within* the group. That is, their regular definitions return outside the group.

However, it's best to define some form of macro to take care of you particular `\footnote` construction. See [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764). Here's an example that produces the same output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\textheight}{10\baselineskip}% Just for this example
\makeatletter
\let\oldfootnote\footnote
\def\footnote{\@ifstar\footnote@star\footnote@nostar}
\def\footnote@star#1{{\let\thefootnote\relax\footnotetext{#1}}}
\def\footnote@nostar{\oldfootnote}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some text\footnote{First footnote}\par
Here is some text\footnote*{Second footnote}\par
Here is some text\footnote{Last footnote}
\end{document}
```