# Is there a way to change the font for a single word?

Tags: fonts

Is there a way to change the font for a single word?

I am using the article document class in LaTex, and I want a Latin word to be italicized but in a different type italics than is used in the remainder of my document.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the principle of [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), the "mixable" font macros like `\textsf{\itshape ...}` could be of use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm
\newcommand{\latinword}[1]{\textsf{\itshape #1}}%
\begin{document}
Here is a word in \textit{italics} and a Latin \latinword{verbum}.
\end{document}
```