# Custom parameters for formatting images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I am a LaTeX newbie working on creating my first custom LaTeX class.
I would like to know if it's possible to define parameters for `\includegraphics` such as `width`, `height`, `center`/`right align` etc in the custom class, so that I don't have to retype all this for each of the image that I insert.

Comment: `\includegraphics` does not provide `center` or `right align` keys. What are you referring to specifically regarding this horizontal alignment? This may be something to do with a `figure` environment?

Comment: What I meant was, is there a way to ensure that each of the image that I insert in the document is always of a particular size, and always aligned right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an attempt to be consistent with your way of writing, consider following the approach in [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) by wrapping your desired inputs in a macro. Something like:

```
\newcommand{\mygraphic}[2][,]{% \mygraphic[<opt args>]{<file>}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=50pt,#1]{#2}}%
```

To this you can add `\centering` or `\raggedleft` (for right alignment) or `\raggedright` (for left alignment), perhaps grouped, depending on the exact usage of `\mygraphics`.

In particular, the above definition `\mygraphic[<opt args>]{<file>}` takes an optional first argument where the default image width/height is `\linewidth`/`50pt`. Otherwise, you can override this with your own setting, or add other options.