# How to prevent linebreak in the word ".NET"?

Tags: line-breaking

Sometimes, LaTeX breaks the word ".NET", leaving the dot on the previous line and putting "NET" on the next line. Can I force it to put all four characters either at the first line or at the second line?

Comment: Use `\mbox{.NET}`. In some cases, adding `\usepackage{microtype}` improves the situation too.

Comment: Box it using `\mbox{.NET}` (as suggested in [How can I make a pair of words stick together in line breaks?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99647/5764)) or via `\newcommand{\dotNET}{\mbox{.NET}}` and then use `\dotNET{}`.

Comment: There is *no* feasible line break point between `.` and `N`, so there's probably something else in your setup. Can you try providing a minimal example?

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing. I actually misplaced the dot in the source code. After correcting that, it breaks correctly.