# How to modify horizontal spacing between equation elements globally, or for a single equation?

Tags: spacing, equations

I've noticed that by default, the horizontal spacing between equation elements is pretty tight, and that I can use [commands for horizontal spacing between elements in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/24425).

Still, I don't want to expand the spacing manually *for each element*, if I know I just want some constant horizontal space increase between each element of each equation I write. This means I will repeat what I did for the second equation, all over my text:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \mathcal{C} := \{i : \forall i \exists \mathcal{V}(i) \neq \emptyset\}
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}
        \mathcal{C} := \{i : \forall \, i \, \exists \, \mathcal{V}(i) \, \neq \, \emptyset\}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to globally, or for a single equation at least, modify the default horizontal spacing between each element of each equation in LaTeX?

Comment: The main problem with the above construct is that LaTeX treats `\forall` and `\exists` as ordinary characters.  A number of solutions are discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115432/15925.  For sets I often define `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Set}[2]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{#1
\,\delimsize\vert\, #2}` used as `\Set{i}{\exists j...}`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks! (+1) I can also just write the equations and do some regex substitutions in vim..