# Why doesn't adding space in a renewcommand work?

Tags: spacing

I was looking for a way to add some spacing after quantifiers and found the answer thanks to [Best practice for typesetting quantifiers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115432/best-practice-for-typesetting-quantifiers?answertab=votes#tab-top). The following MWE works perfectly:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\let\existstemp\exists
\let\foralltemp\forall
\renewcommand*{\exists}{\existstemp\,}
\renewcommand*{\forall}{\foralltemp\,}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}

\begin{document}
$\forall m \in \N, \exists n \in \N\colon m < n$
\end{document}
```

However, during my first attempts to solve the problem, I tried

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\renewcommand*{\exists}{\exists\,}
\renewcommand*{\forall}{\forall\,}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}

\begin{document}
$\forall m \in \N, \exists n \in \N\colon m < n$
\end{document}
```

but that crashed LaTeX.

Why didn't this work correctly? Is my working solution the shortest/cleanest one?

Comment: Rather use something like `\let\oldexists\exists\renewcommand{\exists}{\oldexists\,}` or `\makeatletter\g@addto@macro\exists{\,}\makeatother`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TeX is a macro expansion language.

If you define

```
 \renewcommand*{\exists}{\exists\,}
```

Then when `\exists` is encountered it is replaced by its replacement text, then processing starts again so

```
\exists
```

becomes

```
\exists\,
```

which becomes

```
\exists\,\,
```

which becomes

```
 \exists\,\,\,
```

and so on until you run out of input stack.

Comment: Thank you for your super fast answer! I understand what went wrong now. Is using something like `\let\existstemp\exists` the only correct option?

Comment: @Jeroen for `\exists` which is a mathchar token not a macro, yes more or less. For macros you can extract their expansion and add further tokens.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wouldn't it be most sensible to just change the group of the character? Something like `\expandafter\mathchardef\exists\numexpr\the\exists-"3000\relax` (or whatever chiffre, depending on by how many groups you need to shift the character)?

Comment: @tohecz no as I comment above `\exists` is an unexpandable token so `\expandafter` does nothing to it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, there's some `\expandafter` missing... And it would work: `\expandafter\mathchardef\expandafter\exists\the\numexpr\the\exists+"1000\relax` just it centers the symbol on the math axis... :-/

Comment: @tohecz bm does more or less same to change the fam slot to bold, but in the context here I'm not sure that's really the way to go (especially as it's not clear that any mathclass has the desired spacing)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would say that `"1000` (`op`) works pretty well... but then there's the vertical alignment problem.