# How to make big parenthesis in equation?

Tags: brackets

[image]

I am learning how to make like this, would you mind guys to help me? I just can't make a big parenthesis like this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add a compilable code showing what you have tried so far

Comment: `\big(`, `\bigr)`, `\Bigl(`, `\biggl(`, `\left(`, `\right)`, etc. see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for showed example you not need any special parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
(f \text{ continuous}) \Leftrightarrow
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \forall f(x) \in X\ \forall V\ni f(x) \\
    \exists U \ni x \text{ such that } f(U)\subset C
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

for more about writing math see [wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics), [Advanced Mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics), [tutorials/amsmath](https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/amsmath/) etc.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$
\left(\begin{matrix}
\mbox{first row}\\
\mbox{second row}
\end{matrix}\right)
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `mathtools` package defines an optional argument for the column alignment in its `matrix*` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
(f \text{ continuous }) \Leftrightarrow
    \begin{pmatrix*}[l]
    \,\forall f(x) \in X\ \forall V\ni f(x) \\
   \, \exists U \ni x \text{ such that } f(U)\subset C
    \end{pmatrix*}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The construct `gathered` from `amsmath` is the main ingredient below with brackets around provided by `\left(...\right)`.  Note also correct spacing of quantifiers, as given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115451/15925

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Exists}{\exists}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Forall}{\forall}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  (f\ \text{continuous})
  \iff
  \left(
    \begin{gathered}
      \Forall f(x) \in X \quad \Forall V\ni f(x) \\
      \Exists U \ni x\ \text{such that}\ f(U)\subset C
    \end{gathered}
  \right)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```