# space between \exists and \forall

Tags: typography, document-configuration

I'm writting maths papers. I do use a lot of

$ \ exists ; \ forall $

but I have this problem, they glue the next caracter to them. It is really bad for comprehension... So, in my parameter folder, I redefined those two operators like this :

```
\let\oldexist\exists
\renewcommand{\exists}{\oldexist \ }
```

but I'm not quit satisfied because, If for instance i'm writting, it exists an unique... there is a space between \exists and !...

> Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

It is not only linked to those two quantificators, but also if I want to write a math sentence, it is hard to make it clear because everything is glued, one to the other... I want it to be more spaced... that it uses more space horizontaly. For instance :

$ A \subset B ;  B  \subset C $

instead of that : (that's how it appears on the pdf )

$ A \subset B;B  \subset C $

Comment: `\exists` and `\forall` are classified as `\mathord` (ordinary), `;` is a `\mathpunct` (punctuation), and `\subset` is a `\mathrel` (relation, I have no idea what `\subspace` is). Different classes follow different spacing rules. I don’t recommend changing their behavior as they are by design.

Comment: But you are not helping me. The result is bad... I need to do something about it

Comment: That’s why I’m leaving a comment rather than an answer. If you want your math to feel like a sentence, then perhaps *write a sentence*: `for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$` or `\[ f(x)\ge0 \quad \text{for all } x>0 \]`. Also, check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101028/164314) where spaces are added manually depending on the actual situations.

Comment: the spacing of `\exists` and `\forall` is set up for the usual use in constructs such as `\exists x...` as the use here seems to be different the commands could be reclassified (perhaps as `\mathop`? but I can't really guess the intended meaning of `\exists;\forall` or how the three characters should be classified?

Comment: Thank you for the link because I have actually the same problem as the guy. The answers are interesting but they do not resolve the core of the problem.  So the problem is that the sentence looks cramped and I want that it is made automatic that it isn't. All the answer are unfortunately giving a method to do it by hand, which is I think not the mood of Latex...

Comment: @MarineGalantin It is unfortunate indeed. Since you used the tag “typography”, I’ll give my take. IMHO, the problem comes from the poor [kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning) among math typefaces, so it is a problem of design. So, if the designer didn’t/couldn’t account for the spacing, it’s up to the user, which is a common practice when using typefaces for body text in banner/poster titles. See, for instance, [A beginner’s guide to kerning like a designer](https://www.canva.com/learn/kerning/).

Comment: A variant of the @RuixiZhang approach: `\text{\(A \subset B\); \(B \subspace C\).}` I’d recommend you look for a different approach, but if you don’t like the default spacing of `\exists` and `\forall`, you might try variants with a different spacing class, such as `\mathop{\exists} \mathop{\forall}`? I’m not clear exactly what you want, though.

Comment: In my opinion as a professional mathematician you should almost never use `\forall` and `\exists` in formal written mathematics. Of course, this comment does not solve the problem you asked about. Rather, I am suggesting that you have a more serious problem because mathematics should not be written this way. This said, if you do want help with this problem then *please* provide a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that clearly shows what you are trying to do.

Comment: what I want is quit simple, I don't see the point of writting everytime : , /  in order to make it less cramped. My question is how can you override this problem?

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)

Comment: @Andrew Why not? Would you write them out in English or what? What would you do in mathematical logic? (Well, it depends on notation. Certainly you can do without one or other, if you must and there are, of course, ways of symbolising 'for all' without `\forall`, so I guess you could do without them. But it would certainly make things less readable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the question seems to be very popular and without answer, here I post the solution I am using.

I am comparing my solution to the default behaviour of Overleaf.

default :

```
$$ \forall x \in B_r, \  \exists a, \ \exists ! y \colon \mathcal P $$

$$  A \subset B;B \subset C $$
```

mine :

```
$$ \forall x \in B_r, \  \exists a, \ \existu y \colon \mathcal P $$

$$  A \subset B;B \subset C $$
```

[image]

with this configuration for me :

```
\let\oldforall\forall
\renewcommand{\forall}{\oldforall \, }

\let\oldexist\exists
\renewcommand{\exists}{\oldexist \: }

\newcommand\existu{\oldexist! \: }
```

It relies on having smaller spaces. A reference is here : http://www.emerson.emory.edu/services/latex/latex_119.html

where it is written :

> In a math environment, LaTeX ignores the spaces you type and puts in
> the spacing that it thinks is best. LaTeX formats mathematics the way
> it's done in mathematics texts. If you want different spacing, LaTeX
> provides the following four commands for use in math mode:
>
> ```
> \; - a thick space
> \: - a medium space
> \, - a thin space
> \! - a negative thin space
> ```

I included the line with sets because I mentionned that in the original question. If I would like to put more space, currently I would add `\` or `\quad`.