Changing the spacing around \forall command: from a command to a new math operator solution?
I do not like at all the spacing around the command $\forall$ (ditto for $\exists$), because in complex math formulas I always have to add by hand spaces before or after the symbol.
So I tried to redesign it as an operator (that has the spacing I like) the following way
\documentclass{amsart}
\let\oldforall\forall
\let\forall\relax
\DeclareMathOperator{\forall}{\oldforall}

\begin{document}
$\text{text}\forall x\in Y$
\end{document}

I suspect it is quite a pedestrian way to do it, and there must be some side effects not detected by me. What are the suggestions of the experts of this forum?
Edit
Here is what happens without any change
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}
$z=y \forall x\in Y$
\end{document}

Clearly in that case I have to add spaces manually before and even after (the last one is a matter of taste perhaps ...)

By my book, this shouldn't change anything at all, or am I missing something?

quantifiers aren't operators, so I would not alter the spacing. it just makes it harder to read. in some systems, you have e.g. (\forall x) rather than just \forall x. would you really want the larger spacing there?

@cfr yes you are perfectly right and the example you give make my solution a bit ugly but I only use them in formulas without the parenthesis where the spacing problem before the quantifier appears a lot ... do you have a suggestion?

@Wamseln I edited my question to show you the problem and the changes

@cfr also I choose not to simply change the command $\forall$ by adding a space before because in case there is an operator before like $\mid$ then the spacing is too much ...

I certainly wouldn't add spaces after in the manual case. the x belongs with the \forall. and, yes, you have to add space manually after \text{}, but quantifiers aren't special in that regard. $\text{text}x$ needs space added, too.

@cfr I understand your point but note that I have to add space whatever is before in math environment, like any formula or math symbol (not only the text{} command). Actually for complex math expression there is a lot a manual spacing adjustment. Some IA should be required there :)

Looks quite like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438612/82917

I just wouldn't do whatever needs doing at the expense of incorrect spacing between quantifier and variable ... off-topic: you don't need to \let\forall\relax.
