# How to write the limit inferior in math environment?

Tags: math-operators

I got it to work with

```
\mathop{\underline{\lim}}_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)
```

Above looks exactly how I want it to look, but initiating operators twice is odd and it's far from simple

```
\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)
```

Or is it alright?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using the `amsmath` package, you don't have to define a new operator; the package offers `\varliminf` with the correct spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[ \varliminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If this is used often, then declare it as a math operator. It promotes consistency (see [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)) and ease-of-use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\DeclareMathOperator*{\inflim}{\underline{\lim}}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathop{\underline{\lim}}_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \]
\[ \inflim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \]
\end{document}
```

See the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) (section **5.1 Dening new operator names**, p 17) for the use of/difference in `DeclareMathOperator` and its starred variant.