# Conjugation of matrices - How to typeset it?

Tags: typography

Can you help me?

I do not know what to type in order to show the conjugation.

I mean that the matrix B has complex entries and C is the transpose matrix of B, then B* is C with a line above.

How do I do that?

Comment: See [How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14) You can use `\overline{C}`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

If you are referring to the [Conjugate transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose), then the following is what you're after - a standard `\overline`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\conjugatet\overline
\begin{document}
\[
  (\mathbf{A}^*)_{ij} = \conjugatet{\mathbf{A}_{ji}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Following the guideline in [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), I've defined `\conjugatet` to be equivalent to `\overline`.

Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose

Comment: Should be ${}_{ji}$ in one of the two sides of the equation.