# Math lists: commas inside or outside of math mode?

Tags: math-mode, comma-separated-list

I am wondering whether to use that

```
(1) $A_{a}, B_{b}, C_{c}$ # comma in math mode
```

or that

```
(2) $A_{a}$, $B_{b}$, $C_{c}$ # multiple math modes, comma outside math mode
```

Any good reasons for choosing one of those? Thanks :-)

Comment: Related, if not duplicate: [Consistent typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764). There I mention a similar instance that is taken from [DO’s and DON’Ts when typesetting a document](http://chenfuture.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/dos-and-donts-when-typesetting-a-document/). The different between the two is related to line-breaking.

Comment: @Werner Also the spacing is different.