# How to change global figure setting?

Tags: floats, framed

I did

```
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
```

so all of my figures are with frames. This works well, but there is a place I do not want frame, how can I change it locally?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

Once you create a figure, it is set in a box that can move around. However, once set, it stays as is. So, you can temporarily change the style by localizing a change and restyling:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{float,graphicx}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}%
  \caption{This is figure one}
\end{figure}
{\floatstyle{plain}
\restylefloat{figure}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}%
  \caption{This is figure two}
\end{figure}
}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-c}%
  \caption{This is figure three}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

It's best though, for the sake of [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), to wrap this in your own environment, which also localizes the effect:

```
\newenvironment{noboxfigure}[1][ht]
  {\floatstyle{plain}\restylefloat{figure}%
   \begin{figure}[#1]
  }{\end{figure}}
```

Comment: seems I misunderstand sth, I always produce an error: ! Package caption Error: For a successful cooperation of the `wrapfig' package.

Comment: @Ginger: Could you please include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that includes the packages you're using. Something that replicates your current setup, and reproduces the error if you use my suggestion. Do this via [an edit to your original question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/133017/edit).