# What's the best way to do overshadow?

Tags: graphics

I want to have this effect: overshadow an image with a semi-transparent grey/white colored rectangle (say they are the same size and at the same position).

So now the key question is:

Instead of externally creating an empty eps grey/white figure and then do the overlay, is there any better solution??

Comment: Use inkscape to draw your figure. It is easy to deal with transparencies.

Comment: This is something like a programming exercise for me, I am writing a beamer slide, I have 7*5 array of images in this slide and I want to create an effect, that each time only one image is highlighted, the others are all overshadowed with a grey but transparent color, so at this slide, I will have one highlighted, and next slide I will have another highlighted, so... I don't want to do it in inkscape. Thanks though

Comment: Is this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/1837537/1778537 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used the following before (taken from some very old [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) code, and can surely be improved using a `node`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\begin{document}

\noindent
\setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\usebox1
\vskip-\baselineskip
\smash{%
  \tikz{%
    \filldraw[blue,semitransparent] (0mm,0mm) -- (0mm,\ht1) -- (\wd1,\ht1) -- (\wd1,0mm) -- cycle;
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

You can set your image, then overlay a `\tikz` fill that is `semitransparent`.

---

The following utilizes the core of [Harish's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142318/5764), but adds key-value options that can be mixed with that of [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\includegraphics`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xkeyval,graphicx,tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{xkeyval,graphicx,pgf}
\makeatletter
\define@key{tikznode}{opacity}{\def\tikznode@opacity{#1}}
\define@key{tikznode}{fill}{\def\tikznode@fill{#1}}
\newcommand{\customizedIncludeGraphics}[2][,]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \setkeys*{Gin,tikznode}{fill = blue!50, opacity = 0.7, #1}% Set defaults
    \node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep = 0pt, fill = \tikznode@fill, opacity = \tikznode@opacity]
      {\includegraphics{#2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\customizedIncludeGraphics[width=50pt]{example-image-a}
\customizedIncludeGraphics[width=100pt, fill=brown]{example-image-a}
\customizedIncludeGraphics[width=123pt, opacity=0.2]{example-image-a}
\customizedIncludeGraphics[height=2\baselineskip, fill=green, opacity=0.9]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

Defaults are `fill=blue!50` (50% blue fill) and `opacity=0.7` (70% transparent; 0 = fully opaque).

Comment: Is it possible to wrap these up, so that I could just use something like `\customizedIncludeGraphics{example-image-a}`?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, it's [always a good idea](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764). I've updated my answer with that detail, taking some lead from Harish's answer, but adding some key-value processing.

Comment: I think the concept of opacity you said is wrong. `opacity=0.7` represents `30%` transparent rather than `70%` transparent. So `opacity=1` represents fully opaque or `0%` transparent. What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks. Please compile it with `pdflatex -shell-escape inputfilename.tex`.

```
% this filename is inputfilename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape inputfilename.tex
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{image.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}

\psset{xunit=\wd\IBox,yunit=\ht\IBox}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
    \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=orange,opacity=.25](1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space image.\ext}}



\begin{document}
Is this the image, with a yellow transparent layer, you are looking for?

\section*{Original}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}

\section*{With a yellow transparent layer}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{image}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Bonus Answer

```
% this filename is inputfilename.tex
% compile it with pdflatex -shell-escape inputfilename.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{images.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames,cmyk]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\temp{}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\DefineNamedColor[4]{\listgadd{\temp}{#2}}
\input{dvipsnam.def}
\endgroup
\def\do#1{#1,}
\edef\ColorList{\dolistloop{\temp}end}

\usepackage{graphicx,bera}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\psset{xunit=\wd\IBox,yunit=\ht\IBox}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{40pt}{15pt}\selectfont
\psforeach{\x}{\ColorList}
{
    \expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{\x}{end}{}
    {
        \begin{pspicture}(1,1)
            \rput[bl](0,0){\usebox\IBox}
            \psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=\x,opacity=.75](1,1)
            \rput(0.5,.85){\x}
        \end{pspicture}
    }
}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{pgffor,graphicx}
\foreach \compiler/\ext in {latex/tex,dvips/dvi,ps2pdf/ps}{\immediate\write18{\compiler\space images.\ext}}

\pdfximage{images.pdf}
\begin{document}
\noindent\foreach \x in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{\includegraphics[page=\x,scale=.25]{images} }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, why is the original bigger than the modified one even though I use the same scaling factor? What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Using `tikz` again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\myimage}[4]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner sep=0pt, outer sep = 0pt,fill = #1,opacity=#2]{\includegraphics[width=#3]{#4}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
%% \myimage{<color>}{<transparency>}{<width>}{<image file name>}
\noindent\myimage{blue!40}{.7}{.4\linewidth}{example-image-a}
\hfill
\myimage{magenta!40}{.7}{.4\linewidth}{example-image-b}

\noindent\myimage{green!40}{.7}{.4\linewidth}{example-image-c}
\hfill
\myimage{blue!40!green!30}{.7}{.4\linewidth}{example-image}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See, I don't have much `tikz`-foo...

Comment: @Werner: You are surely joking Werner ;-)

Answer (score 4):

For comparison, this is how you can achieve the same effect in ConTeXt

```
% Search figures in TEXMF tree
\setupexternalfigures
    [location={local,global,default}]

\definecolor[transparentblue][b=1,t=.5,a=1]

\starttext

\startcombination[nx=2]
  {\externalfigure[mill.png]]}
  {Normal figure}
  {\externalfigure[mill.png][background={foreground,color}, backgroundcolor=transparentblue]}
  {Transparent overshadow}
\stopcombination
```

[image]

The idea is pretty straight forward. Each `externalfigure` is a `frame`, and one of the properties of the frame is that you can set the `background`. One of the default backgrounds is `color`, which fills the background with `backgroundcolor`.

Now what you want can be thought of as a *background* that is placed over the content, rather than under it. Specifying `background={foreground,color}` tells ConTeXt to first place the `foreground` layer (that is the layer containing the content) and then place the `color` layer on top of it.

This idea works with any ConTeXt environment that accepts a `background` key: framed, framedtext, TABLE, page backgrounds, etc.

If you want to apply this to multiple images, then you can define

```
\defineexternalfigure[tint][background={foreground,color}, backgroundcolor=transparentblue]
```

and use it as follows

```
\externalfigure[filename][tint]
```

This will add the overshadow to the figure. If you want, you can override the shadow color using

```
\externalfigure[filename][tint][backgroundcolor=transparentred]
```

Here is a complete example showing this.

```
% Search figures in TEXMF tree
\setupexternalfigures
    [location={local,global,default}]

\definecolor[transparentblue][b=1,t=.5,a=1]
\definecolor[transparentred][r=1,t=.5,a=1]

\defineexternalfigure[tint][background={foreground,color}, backgroundcolor=transparentblue]

\starttext

\startcombination[nx=2]
  {\externalfigure[mill.png][tint]}
  {Default tint}
  {\externalfigure[mill.png][tint][backgroundcolor=transparentred]}
  {Override shadow color}
\stopcombination

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]