# Weird behaviour of \FuncSty in algorithm2e

Tags: fonts, algorithm2e

I'm using the small capital font \textsc{MyAlgorithm} several times inside my algorithm2e environment as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\FuncSty{${\textsc{FirstAlgorithm}}(a, b))$} \Begin{
  $ X \leftarrow \textsc{AnotherAlgorithm}(c, d)$\;
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I don't undestand why FirstAlgorithm has a completely and unexpected (looks like \textit) font and AnotherAlgorithm later looks as it should? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\FuncSty` sets its argument using `\texttt`, which is inherited by `\textsc` (from [`algorithm2e.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/tex/algorithm2e.sty)):

```
\newcommand{\FuncSty}[1]{\textnormal{\texttt{#1}}\unskip}%\SetFuncSty{texttt}
```

Technically you don't need `\FuncSty` in this instance, but I'd suggest defining a macro to perform your function name formatting [consistently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered,vlined]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\newcommand{\FuncName}[1]{\mbox{\normalfont\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \FuncSty{${\textsc{FirstAlgorithm}}(a, b))$}
  \Begin{
    $ X \leftarrow \textsc{AnotherAlgorithm}(c, d)$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  $\FuncName{FirstAlgorithm}(a, b)$
  \Begin{
    $X \leftarrow \FuncName{AnotherAlgorithm}(c, d)$\;
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Your use of the `ruled` style provided by [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) does not seem appropriate (the double-rule at the top is supposed to contain an algorithm `\caption`).

Comment: Pretty good explanation. I'll pay attention to this in the future.