# Remove macro's functionality via a regular expression

Tags: macros, bold

I want find all `\textbf` in my `.tex` file and delete it, together with it's argument braces `{}`. For example, I want to change:

1. `\textbf{text}` to `text`
2. `\textbf{text \textit{textbis}}` to `text \textit{textbis}`
3. `\textbf{\textit{\textls[-5]{textbis}} text}` to `\textit{\textls[-5]{textbis}} text`
4. `\textbf{\textit{X{textbis}} text}` to `\textit{X{textbis}} text` (where `X` is a paragraph break).

I tried to use `\\textbf\{([^}]*)\}` in `\1` but it didn't work because it stops at first `}`.

Comment: You can not match braces to arbitrary depth with a (real) regular expression, that's essentially what "regular" means.

Comment: It is easiest to add `\let\textbf\relax` to your document preamble if you want to remove the functionality of `\textbf` altogether. You can then leave `\textbf` in your document and it will have no effect.

Comment: This is a fine topic for nested lists handling. Back to TeX, I use `\def\textbf#1{#1}`.

Comment: @Werner `\let\texbf\@firstofone`

Comment: This shows that one should **always** use semantic markup. That is, instead of using `\textbf{...}` define a macro say `\important`. That way, if at a later stage you want to change how the output looks, you can just redefine the macro `\important`.

Comment: @Aditya: Yes, as suggested in [Consistent typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)...

Comment: I bet you there is an elegant solution in Sublime Text. Is there way to enter a variable in the "Find" field for the "Search and Replace" feature of Sublime (or any other editor)?

Comment: i dont want put nothing in the preamble (only necessary to stat tex ^^).

Then there's a system to clear my file quicly with a regular expression that understand when finish a determinate gruop? Or i need delete all \textbf and after find all { } not necessary manually?

THX all again

Vitaliano

Comment: Why not (and someone cleverer than me will say why not) define a macro:
`\newcommand{\notbold}[1]{#1}` and change all your `\textbf{`s to s\notbold{`s (you don't even need regex)?  This then doesn't wipe out `\textbf` in case you need it again.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by @David Carlisle you cannot match an *arbitrary* number of well-nested `{` `}` pairs.
But, from a practical perspective, you may know an upper-bound on the maximum nesting level. If this bound is known, then it is possible to write a regular expression recognizing well-parenthesised expressions up to the maximum nesting level.

To recognise `\texbf{normal text}` (max nest = 1) you can do

\textbf{([^{}]*)}

forbidding `{` inside the brackets is a precaution to never match things with nesting level greater than your maximum.

To match things with max nest = 2 you can do the following:

1. first you match `\\textbf\{`
2. then you match any non bracket character with `[^{}]*`
3. now you may have finished matching the contents (the actual nesting level is 1) and happily match the ending `\}`
4. or, you could be in a position with an open bracket. In this case you need to match something with nesting level 0, and then match the closed bracket.

Steps 2, 3 and 4 correspond to `[^{}]*(\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)?` which may be repeated so you can match things like `\textbf{bla\bla{bla}bla\bla{bla}bla}`

So all in all the max nest level = 2 regex looks like this

```
\\textbf\{(([^{}]*(\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)?)*)\}
```

We can extrapolate the scheme for max nest = N greater than 2:

```
\\textbf\{(([^{}]*(\{RN\}[^{}]*)?)*)\}
```

where

```
R1 = [^{}]*
RN = ([^{}]*(\{R(N-1)\}[^{}]*)?)*
```

So for example with max nest = 3 you get

```
\\textbf\{(([^{}]*(\{(([^{}]*(\{[^{}]*\}[^{}]*)?)*)\}[^{}]*)?)*)\}
```

which is sufficient to catch all the cases you mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use non-greedy quantifiers,

replace `\\textbf\{(.*?)\}` with `\1`

Ok, as Werner mentioned, this only works with non-nested commands.
I think, there is no simple solution for this and it's a parser job.

If you want to do it anyway with Regex, you could replace the non-`\textbf`-brackets with a non-used symbol, and at then end remove the `\textbf`-brackets and change the symbols back to brackets:

1) Replace all closing non-`\textbf`-brackets `}` with Symbol A,

2) Replace all opening non-`\textbf`-brackets `{` with Symbol B,

3) Replace the remaining `\textbf{` and `}` (from `\textbf`) with nothing,

4) Replace Symbol A with `{` and Symbol B with `}`

@Step 1 and 2:

Step 1: `}` -> Smybol A, in my example german `ö`:

```
(?<=(?<!\\textbf)\{(?!.*?\{)).*?\}
```

Replace this expression with `\1ö` (I didn't found a better solution for this expression)

Then do Step 2: `{` -> Symbol B, in my example german `ä`

```
(?<!\\textbf)\{(?!.*?\{)
```

Replace this expression with `ä`.

Redo these steps as many nested levels you have. Then follow the remaining steps.

---

Well, this is more a regex-macro and a workaround than a solid regex, but it should work.

Comment: Doesn't "greedy" refer to the same problem the OP experienced? That is, the first `}` is considered the closing group for `\textbf`, which is not always the case?

Comment: Step 1 say me invalid pattern in look-behind

Comment: It's working with Notepad++

Comment: i'm trid your code in first step in this text : "in alcuni casi, patologia. \textbf{\textit{L’immagine} corporea} è un’immagine dinamica che dipende da fattori non solo biologici, relativi ai cambiamenti fisiologici del corpo, ma anche psicologici e sociali. Il corpo, infatti, è il crocevia delle interazioni sociali,  dei riconoscimenti e delle accettazioni, è la “visualizzazione” del progetto identitario di ciascuno.}

\end{document}"


he find **L’immagine}** and **document}**

Comment: I've edited my post again (numbering).
Look again at step 1: Yes, it will find **L'immagine}**, but in 2 groups: **L'immagine** is `\1` and **}** is `\2`.
That's why you replace the pattern with `\1ä`.