# Can I turn a collection of optional parameters into a macro?

Tags: macros, key-value

I currently have several environments from `mdframed` that have a large number of options that are shared between them. The situation looks like

```
\newmdtheoremenv[options0,options1]{env1}{Environment 1}
\newmdtheoremenv[options0,options2]{env2}{Environment 2}
\newmdtheoremenv[options0,options3]{env3}{Environment 3}
```

etc., where in place of `options0`, etc, there are a long list of various options like `backgroundcolor=red!1`, `leftmargin=0.5in`, etc. I would prefer not to write out all the arguments in `options0` repeatedly for each of these environments, and I was wondering if I could use a macro to do this. I tried

```
\newcommand{\myopts}{options0}
\newmdtheoremenv[\myopts,options1]{env1}{Environment 1}
\newmdtheoremenv[\myopts,options2]{env2}{Environment 2}
\newmdtheoremenv[\myopts,options3]{env3}{Environment 3}
```

but it did not work, telling me that there is a Package kvsetkeys error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related Question: [Defining mdframe style by reference to another style](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168755/defining-mdframe-style-by-reference-to-another-style).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a good thing, since it promotes [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764). However, your key-value argument needs to be *expanded* before it can be properly assigned using key-value pairs. For this you have at least two options:

1. Explicitly insert `\expandafter`s to jump over the construction until you reach the optional argument(s):

   ```
   \expandafter\newmdtheoremenv\expandafter[\myopts]{theorem}{Theorem}
   ```
2. Implicitly expand the contents using

   ```
   \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup%
     \noexpand\newmdtheoremenv[\myopts]{theorem}{Theorem}}\x
   ```

   The above *magic* defines `\x` as an expansion of everything but `\newmdtheoremenv` (including `\endgroup`). That is, only `\myopts` is expanded. If we assume that `\myopts` was defined using

   ```
   \newcommand{\myopts}{
      outerlinewidth  = 2             ,%
      roundcorner     = 10pt          ,%
      leftmargin      = 40            ,%
      rightmargin     = 40            ,%
      backgroundcolor = yellow!40     ,%
      outerlinecolor  = blue!70!black ,% 
      innertopmargin  = \topskip      ,%
      splittopskip    = \topskip       %
   }
   ```

   Then, after defining `\x` (using `\edef`), `\x` resembles (taken from the terminal):

   ```
   \endgroup \newmdtheoremenv [ outerlinewidth = 2 ,roundcorner = 10pt ,leftmarg
   in = 40 ,rightmargin = 40 ,backgroundcolor = yellow!40 ,outerlinecolor = blue!7
   0!black ,innertopmargin = \topskip ,splittopskip = \topskip ]{theorem}{Theorem
   }
   ```

   This is exactly what you're after.

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

While Werner answers the question posted,  I would recommend an approach that uses `mdfdefinestyle` instead when talking about options specifically for the `mdframed` environment.

Define each of the collection of styles in an`\mdfdefinestyle`, and then combine them as desired:

```
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myopts,style=options1]{env1}{Environment 1}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myopts,style=options2]{env2}{Environment 2}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myopts,style=options3]{env3}{Environment 3}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{myopts}{%
   outerlinewidth  = 2             ,%
   roundcorner     = 10pt          ,%
   leftmargin      = 40            ,%
   rightmargin     = 40            ,%
   outerlinecolor  = blue!70!black ,% 
   innertopmargin  = \topskip      ,%
   splittopskip    = \topskip       %
}

\mdfdefinestyle{options1}{%
   backgroundcolor = yellow!40,
}

\mdfdefinestyle{options2}{
   backgroundcolor = blue!20,
   frametitlerulecolor=blue,
   roundcorner=0pt,
}

\mdfdefinestyle{options3}{%
   backgroundcolor = red!20,
   frametitle={Options 3 Title},
   frametitlebackgroundcolor=olive!40,
   frametitlerule=true,       
   roundcorner=4pt,
}


\newcommand{\myopts}{options0}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myopts,style=options1]{env1}{Environment 1}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myopts,style=options2]{env2}{Environment 2}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myopts,style=options3]{env3}{Environment 3}

\begin{document}

\begin{env1}
    This is \textbf{env1}.
\end{env1}

\begin{env2}
    This is \textbf{env2}.
\end{env2}

\begin{env3}
    This is \textbf{env3}.
\end{env3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like this solution. At least for the specific case of `mdframed`, it is cleaner than the other solution. Thanks.