# Defining mdframe style by reference to another style

Tags: mdframed

I'm wanting to define an mdframe style "studies", by reference to mdframe style "mpdframe". In the example shown, the difference would be to add a frame title, "Studies".

The following code does not produce errors, but neither does it produce the desired effect.

```
%   Principal MPD frame type
\mdfdefinestyle{mpdframe}{
    frametitlebackgroundcolor   =black!15,
    frametitlerule          =true,
        roundcorner     =10pt,
        middlelinewidth     =1pt,
        innermargin     =0.5cm,
        outermargin     =0.5cm,
        innerleftmargin     =0.5cm,
        innerrightmargin        =0.5cm,
        innertopmargin      =\topskip,
        innerbottommargin   =\topskip,
            }
%   Studies
\mdfdefinestyle{studies}{%
\mdfapptodefinestyle{mpdframe}{frametitle={Studies}}
    }
\newmdenv[style=studies]{studies}
```

Can this be done another way?

Ideally, I want to define numerous styles in this way, by reference to this base style, rather than continually repeating the option commands.

Comment: Related Question: [Can I turn a collection of optional parameters into a macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168615/can-i-turn-a-collection-of-optional-parameters-into-a-macro).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply use one `style` when defining another:

```
\mdfdefinestyle{studies}{%
    style=mpdframe,% <------ previously defined style
    frametitle={Studies},
}
```

[image]

### Notes:

- You also need `\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}` when using `tikz` within `mdframed`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%   Principal MPD frame type
\mdfdefinestyle{mpdframe}{
    frametitlebackgroundcolor   =black!15,
    frametitlerule          =true,
        roundcorner     =10pt,
        middlelinewidth     =1pt,
        innermargin     =0.5cm,
        outermargin     =0.5cm,
        innerleftmargin     =0.5cm,
        innerrightmargin        =0.5cm,
        innertopmargin      =\topskip,
        innerbottommargin   =\topskip,
            }
%   Studies
\mdfdefinestyle{studies}{%
        style=mpdframe,
        frametitle={Studies},
    }
\newmdenv[style=studies]{studies}

\begin{document}

\begin{studies}
\lipsum[1]
\end{studies}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you. Felt it had to be something simple like that. Excellent.