# Can someone helps me understanding the following code?

Tags: mdframed

I am trying to replicate the code used in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168755/defining-mdframe-style-by-reference-to-another-style)

And I am having trouble understanding the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%   Principal MPD frame type
\mdfdefinestyle{mpdframe}{
    frametitlebackgroundcolor   =black!15,
    frametitlerule          =true,
        roundcorner     =10pt,
        middlelinewidth     =1pt,
        innermargin     =0.5cm,
        outermargin     =0.5cm,
        innerleftmargin     =0.5cm,
        innerrightmargin        =0.5cm,
        innertopmargin      =\topskip,
        innerbottommargin   =\topskip,
            }
%   Studies
\mdfdefinestyle{studies}{%
        style=mpdframe,
        frametitle={Studies},
    }
\newmdenv[style=studies]{studies}

\begin{document}

\begin{studies}
\lipsum[1]
\end{studies}
\end{document}
```

Firstly, what does `innertopmargin=topskip` means
And secondly, why the framemethod has to be tikz instead?
The answerer said that the tikz is used but where?

Comment: `mdframed` can draw frames with Latex commands (e.g., `\rule`), or with TikZ, or with `PSTricks`. You choose, and it loads the required packages. For the margins, `Figure 2: adjustable lengths of mdframed` in the manual (`texdoc mdframed`) illustrates them.

Comment: "`\topskip` Minimum distance between the top of the page body and the baseline of the first line of text." - from the manual (`texdoc latex2e`).