# Multiple lines in equation environment

Tags: equations, scaling, arrays, fractions

I have to put an two equations inside one `equation` environment. I could do it with this piece o code:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{ccl}

\nabla \cdot F & = & \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}i + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}j + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right) \cdot (F_{1}i + F_{2}j + F_{3}k) \\
               & = & \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial F_{3}}{\partial z}
\end{array}!
\end{equation}
```

Which gives me this image:

[image]

The problem is cause when I use the `array`, my fractions get smaller. Here is a single line equation and how I would like to preserve my fraction size in a environment with more than 1 equation.

[image]

Can I achieve this result?

Comment: If you're using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), then use `\dfrac` instead of `\frac`. However, for such alignment, it's easier to use `\begin{align}`...`\end{align}`, *unless* you want to number the entire multi-line equation with a single tag. Then you need something different.

Comment: Yes, and want to number the entire multi-line equation. The \dfrac worked, but it seems that the lines are get over each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try `\dfrac{}{}` instead of `\frac{}{}`. Include the `amsmath` (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

The "d" stands for displaysize(or style), you can of course do a `\displaystyle` on every symbol, but that would be too clumsy.

EDIT: Corrected on Steven B. Segletes suggestion.

Comment: That would be `\displaystyle`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a reworking of what you want to achieve using [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `aligned` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\pfrac}[2][]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}% \pfrac[<top>]{<bottom>}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    \nabla \cdot F &= \biggl( \pfrac{x}i + \pfrac{y}j + \pfrac{z} \biggr)
                        \cdot \bigl(F_1 i + F_2 j + F_3 k \bigr) \\
                   &= \pfrac[F_1]{x}+ \pfrac[F_2]{y} + \pfrac[F_3]{z}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The addition of `\pfrac[<top>}{<bottom>}` is to simplify your notation and provide [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764).