# I want to make an equation, but I can't get what I want on the correct lines

Tags: equations, arrays

```
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=f(x,y,u(x,y))$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=g(x,y,u(x,y))$$
$$u(x_0,y_0)=u_0$$
```

I want to write this but as an equation, I have tried

```
\begin{equation}
& =\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=f(x,y,u(x,y))\\
& =\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=g(x,y,u(x,y))\\
u(x_0,y_0)=u_0
\end{equation}
```

but can't get it to work.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated

Comment: 1. Don't use `$$`; use `\[ \]` instead. 2. You can not use `&` inside an `equation`; use `align` instead of `equation`. Then `\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y) &= f(x,y,u(x,y))\\ `.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do I get each statement onto individual lines, but for the entire equation to be marked as one equation.

Comment: Use `aligned` inside `equation` then. See: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171473/14757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 %(xyz) as a placeholder
 \begin{alignat}{2}
  (xyz) &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y) &&=f(x,y,u(x,y))\\
  (xyz) &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y) &&=g(x,y,u(x,y))\\
  (xyz) &= u(x_0,y_0) &&=u_0
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very close, just I wanted them all to be called one equation though. Ive worked out how to do it from Singur's comment above

Comment: The space after equal sign is wrong since the correct use is `&=`.

Comment: yes, i edited it...

Comment: will you also post a new image to go with the modified code?

Comment: everything edited!