# Chapter name in header of page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm looking to get chapter names in the header of my document. I am using the `article` class, and the code below is an example of how each chapter/section begins.

```
\noindent {\huge \textbf {Chapter 1}}
\section{Introduction}
```

What I'm looking to achieve is a header with the following on the right-hand side:

```
CHAPTER 1: INTRODUCTION
```

The header for the pages in chapter two should be:

```
CHAPTER 2: THEORY
```

and so on.

Could anyone assist me with this? I know a little about the `fancyhdr` package, but as I understand, it uses the chapter name in the `book` class, while I am looking to insert text, and the section name in the `article` class.

Comment: For the sake of [consistency](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764), I suggest creating a macro to set your chapters, just like `\chapter` in other document classes that have them. What do you want on the left page header? Do you only have one `\section` per "chapter"?

Comment: ...and what about numbering of the sections like what usually happens when you use `\section`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not using the `book` class if you have chapters?

Comment: @Werner I would like the left page header blank. There is only one section, and several subsections per chapter. There is a code snippet that I found lately that suppresses the number beside the Introduction.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I'm not using the book class as the document is a scientific report, and contains an abstract. This doesn't seem to be well supported by this class. If possible, I would like to continue using the article class.

Comment: I don't know too much about why you should choose one class over another, but I am using `report` class. You can have chapters (and I have them in my `fancyhdr` output. Incidentally, I have just inserted an abstract by just writing "Abstract" and putting some text after it. I don't really understand the point of the abstract environment TBH!

Comment: The report class gives you `\chapter` *and* an `abstract` environment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina indeed that is why I suggested it - but I decided I personally had more control over how it looked if I ditched the specific abstract environment. I need to add titles and dates and stuff to my abstract page :)

Comment: @FionaSmith Yes, I understand you; my comment was mainly addressed to Matthew :)

Answer (score 4):

In the following minimal example I reformatted `\section` to be like `\chapter` by making it a `display` and inserting `Chapter~` before the numbering (all provided by [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{fancyhdr,titlesec,lipsum}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{}% No header on Left pages

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Chapter~\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{2.3ex plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{Chapter~\thesection: #1}}{}}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{A new section}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Effectively `\section` now looks like `\chapter` (nothing has been done to affect the way `\section*` is handled).

Answer (score 1):

The `titlesec` package allows to create new sectioning levels. So I create a `chapter` level, between `part` and `section`, that doesn't start a new page since it is in an article. Of course I have to define its formatting and how it appears in the `headers/footers` and in the `table of contents`. All this `can be done by titlesec and its companion packages`titleps`and`titletoc`.  So here is an attempt:

```
\documentclass[english, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage[pagestyles, newparttoc, explicit,outermarks]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\large\bfseries\boldmath}{§~\thesection}{0.6em}{\itshape#1}%

\titleclass{\chapter}{straight}[\part]
\newcounter{chapter}
\counterwithin*{section}{chapter}
\renewcommand{\chaptertitlename}{\chaptername}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[block]{\Large\bfseries\boldmath\filleft\lsstyle}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\enspace\thechapter: } {1em} {\MakeUppercase{#1}}%
 \titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{2.5\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}

\makeatletter
 \renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
\chapter*{\contentsname}%
\@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]{\medskip\bfseries}%{1.5em}
{\contentslabel[\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel}.]{1.5em}}{}{\hfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]
\titlecontents{section}[2.5em]{}%{1.5em}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.2em}}{}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.} \contentspage}

 \newpagestyle{mine}{%
\settitlemarks{chapter, section}%\ifthesection{}
\sethead[][{§\,\thesection.\enspace\itshape\sectiontitle}][]{}{\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter.\enspace\chaptertitle}}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}}%

\pagestyle{mine}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
%
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-2]
\section{A First Section. }
\lipsum[1-2]%
\section{A Second Section}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapter{Theory}

\lipsum[1]
\section{Section A}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Section B}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your even headers.

Comment: @Werner: You're right. I forgot to check all the details. This is due to the fact that in tne article class, the `tableofcontents`  is a `\section` command. All other even page headers, which I didn't join to my answer, are normal. I'll check for a workaround.

Comment: @Werner: Finally it had nothing to do with table of contents (which I turned into a chapter any way), but in the way the marks were set. I changed the default `innermarks` to `outermarks`and used the `ifthesection` test.

Answer (score 0):

If you just a line in the beginning of each chapter redefining you header you should be able to achieve this using fancyhdr. You can read more about using the fancyhdr package [here](http://texblog.org/2007/11/07/headerfooter-in-latex-with-fancyhdr/).

The following code should give you what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}}

\begin{document}
\noindent {\huge \textbf {Chapter 1}}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{CHAPTER 1: \rightmark}
\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\noindent {\huge \textbf {Chapter 2}}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{CHAPTER 2: \rightmark}
\section{A new section}
\end{document}
```