# Using whitespace in TeX informatively to typeset predicate calculus

Tags: spacing

I am using this [set of macros](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~trebla/PToP-latex/PToP-macro.tex) to write up some predicate calculus notes.

The issue I am having is that in the math environment of LaTeX, things are automatically spaced in ways that are not most convenient for reading when dealing with predicate calculus. In particular, I am sorely missing the ability to manually use horizontal whitespace to delineate operators in order to allow the eye to automatically understand precedence.

Here's an example:

let's say I want to write the following statement:

```
x /\ y /\ z => a
```

In order to make it unambiguous, I could put in parantheses:

```
(x /\ y /\ z) => a
```

Or I could put in white space, along with making the operator slightly larger (which I am not able to show here):

```
x /\ y /\ y /\ z   =>  a
```

I prefer the last option sometimes, if I would have to use too many parentheses otherwise. How can I get LaTeX to help? This was something that was easy to do in a WYSIWYG editor...

Comment: See [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) (possible duplicate). You should define a spacing command like `\newcommand{\implyspace}{\quad}` which would allow you to easily modify it throughout your document (following the advice referenced in [Consistent typography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)). Alternatively (perhaps better), define your operator (say) `\newcommand{\simp}{\quad\imp\quad}`.

Comment: @Werner Thank you. Could you write this up as an answer so that I can give you internet points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) define a macro for use as your implication. For example,

```
\newcommand{\simp}{\quad\imp\quad}
```

which will insert `\quad` before *and* after `\imp`. Alternatively, see [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74353/5764) for alternatives to `\quad`.