# How do you use Psvectorian?

Tags: xetex, header-footer, pstricks, fancyhdr

Can someone provide a short explanation or example of using [`psvectorian`](http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.pdf)? 
http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/psvectorian.pdf

Specifically, I am looking for an explanation of how to download required documentation, files, styles, etc (I downloaded the files from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian) to no avail). I also would like to know how to use these ornaments in the body of the document as well as the `fancyhdr` environment for both centered headers and footers. Lastly, can I use `psvectorian` while typesetting in XeLaTeX?

Maybe there is a quick and simple example someone can provide?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`pst-vectorian`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-vectorian) should form part of your distribution already, as it is shipped with both TeX Live and MiKTeX. Note that in order to use the package, you need to use

```
\usepackage{psvectorian}
```

in your document preamble (it's location on CTAN is spelled differently from the actual package name). However, if even this doesn't work, then you can [download the entire package ZIP](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian.zip) and store its contents in your `texmf-local` folder. Then, run `texhash` to update the TeX File Name Database (FNDB), after which you should be able to use the package without problem.

The following works as-is under LaTeX or XeLaTeX:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian,fancyhdr,lipsum,multido}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\fancyhead[C]{\psvectorian[height=.7\baselineskip]{187}}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  \makebox[0pt]{\thepage}%
  \smash{\raisebox{-\baselineskip}{\makebox[0pt]{\psvectorian[width=\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{85}}}}}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  \psvectorian[width=.3\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{47}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{center}
  \quad\multido{\i=102+1}{7}{\psvectorian[height=.8\baselineskip]{\i}\quad}
\end{center}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Ornament usage is done using `\psvectorian[<options>]{<number>}` where `<number>` is taken from the [list of ornaments in the documentation](https://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian/doc/psvectorian.pdf). If you plan on using some symbols more frequently, it's best to [define a macro with some contextual name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) so you can reference it easier. For example,

```
\newcommand{\owl}[1][]{\psvectorian[#1]{123}}
```

Comment: Don't know why but your MWE works with `XeTeX` but not with `LaTeX`. The error is `15: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 
                             
l.15 ...dth=.3\textwidth,height=\baselineskip]{47}`

Comment: @Colas: No problem here (TL 2016). That type of error is synonymous to compiling under pdfLaTeX, not LaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: Yes you are right