# How to draw lettering on tile or ceramic in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

I know that LaTeX is able to do incredible things. I want to know how to achieve something like this:

[image]

I need to draw an oval placard such as:

[image]

But I have not idea how to do it. I'm not asking for someone here do it for me, simply know about an example (if possible) or a guideline for achieve it. Of course mine has a different message from the photos. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use PGFornament package (which is not on CTAN but you can search for it) see this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159597/ornaments-in-pgfornament-to-be-at-the-corners-at-every-page . I'm hoping the reviewers will wait your response before they mark this as a duplicate

Comment: May I ask why you wish to use TeX to do this? Why not Inkscape or GIMP or other graphical tool? I'm not sure, from the examples you've posted, that TeX is the best tool for this. That is not to say that it cannot be done using TeX. But that doesn't mean it is best done in TeX so I'm curious why you'd want to go this route, especially if you have no idea how bumpy said route may turn out to be.

Comment: @cfr Well, I was curious to see if TeX would be possible to do that. I see people do amazing things and I want to learn from it. Maybe Inkscape would be a better tool for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Ornament

Just for fun with PSTricks. The package `psvectorian` is not included in TeXLive so you need to download it from http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/vectorian/ and install it. Unfortunately, the manual in English is not available.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
%\renewcommand*{\psvectorianDefaultColor}{black}%
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psframe(-5,-5)(5,5)
%haut+bas
\rput[tl](-3,5){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{71}}
\rput[bl](-3,-5){\psvectorian[width=6cm,flip]{71}}
%coins
\rput[tl](-5,5){\psvectorian[width=2cm]{63}}
\rput[tr](5,5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,mirror]{63}}
\rput[bl](-5,-5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,flip]{63}}
\rput[br](5,-5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,flip,mirror]{63}}
% cotes
\rput[bl]{-90}(-5,3){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{46}}
\rput[bl]{90}(5,-3){\psvectorian[width=6cm]{46}}
%texte+soulignement+chapeau
\rput(0,0){\Huge Garbage Collector}
\rput[t](0,-0.5){\psvectorian[width=5cm]{75}}
\rput[b](0,0.5){\psvectorian[width=5cm]{69}}
%oiseaux
\rput[tr]{-30}(-1,2.5){\psvectorian[width=2cm]{57}}
\rput[tl]{30}(1,2.5){\psvectorian[width=2cm,mirror]{57}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just a note: as per http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175769/how-do-you-use-psvectorian, it seems `psvectorian` is in TexLive under the name [pst-vectorian](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-vectorian)