# Using psvectorian, pgfornament or similar with Share LaTeX

Tags: pstricks, sharelatex, pgfornament

I would like to use [these](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-vectorian/psvectorian.pdf) or similar ornaments in my LaTeX document. However I use Share Latex (and have no other option since this is a collab project, and its too late to change), and pgfornament doesn't seem to be supported. I get the error:

`Latex error: File 'pgfornament.sty' not found`

Can I manually add this file. Where do I download it and how do I add it to Share LaTeX?

I've also tried using:

`\usepackage{pstricks,psvectorian}` Instead.

This does not give an error, so it must have found the file. However, when I try the code provided in the SE answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175769/how-do-you-use-psvectorian) or any of the answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41159/does-anybody-know-a-good-source-of-free-ornaments-decorations-frames-backgr) I get an error: `Undefined Control Sequence`, on any line that includes the `\psvectorian[]{}`command. And the ornaments do not show up in the compiled document.

So how can I add a range of pre-made ornaments, such as psvectorian or pgfornament to a document made in Share LaTeX?

Comment: There's no `pgfornament.sty` in TeX Live.

Comment: What is TeX Live, and can I add `pgfornament.sty` to it myself? If not, do you know any alternatives that will work with ShareLaTeX?

Comment: Aparrently pst-vectorian should form part of my distribution already, as it is shipped with both TeX Live and MiKTeX. So do you know why this package isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

After some fiddling I've found the answer.

Click Menu, then change the compiler from PDFLaTeX to LaTeX or XeLaTeX. This will allow you to use the `psvectorian` package which includes all of the ornaments (vectorians) in the `pgfornament` package.

Be warned, this may interfere with other packages in your document.