# How to place a line for "N.A." at a cell of a table

Tags: tables

I see some tables with a horizontal line placed at the middle of a cell, for terms not available or not applicable. For example, how shall I replace the "N.A." below with such a line?

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\hline
Auctions of & P\_value &  $\widehat{\theta}$ \\
\midrule
2  & 0.375 & $\underset{(0.230)}{0.354}$ \\
3  & 0.002 & N.A. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Is `\---` enough? Or maybe `\--` or even `\verb+-+`.

Comment: @Sigur `\---` and `\--`? Did you mean `---` and `--`?

Comment: @egreg, I always had used that. What is the difference? Non breakable?

Comment: @Sigur `\-` gives a discretionary hyphen, so `\---` is a discretionary hyphen followed by an en-dash.

Comment: @egreg, but with no space between them? So is not possible to see the difference between `---` and `\---`?

Comment: @Sigur I don't understand what you're saying; `\-` is a control symbol, so it's already a complete control sequence name; `\---` is *three tokens*: `\-`, `-` and `-`; unless you change the definition of `\-`, `\-` is a discretionary hyphen and, at typesetting time, `--` is converted to an en-dash.

Comment: @egreg, after testing your codes I understood. `foo-foo\-foo--foo---foo` `foo-foo\-foo\--foo---foo` `foo-foo\-foo\--foo\---foo`

Comment: @JieWei, please, see on the comments above that the right one is *without back slash*. `---`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest [defining a command `\NA`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) that holds an em-dash `---`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,amsmath}
\newcommand{\NA}{---}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \toprule
  Auctions of & \detokenize{P_value} &  $\widehat{\theta}$ \\
  \midrule
  2  & 0.375 & $\underset{(0.230)}{0.354}$ \\
  3  & 0.002 & \NA \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This way, if you don't like it later (in life), just change the definition to something more suitable (perhaps an en-dash `--`).