# adding large curly bracket and black title background

Tags: formatting, brackets

I tried to add curly brackate using

1. `\left{` , `\begin{array}{@{}ll}` but no help. What is the way to add large brackate to cover as in image?
2. Is is possible to create black strip as in image behind `Users-schema`?

Source code DEMO : https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5374a2ebeb2b8d651828ef64f

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf {User schema}
\end{center}

\setstretch{1.5}
\textbf {ID : }  \textcolor{red}{ObjectId }- Id do registro \\
\textbf {Name: } \textcolor{red}{ String  } - Name co usuario \\
\textbf {date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date } - Date de Cadastro \\
\textbf {ren\_date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date }  -  Data de 

\textbf {email: } \textcolor{red}{ String } - Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit. 

\[
\text{accesslog: \textcolor{red}{ Array }}
  \left(
  \begin{array}{@{}ll}
  \left\{\begin{tabular}{l}
       \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.\\
       \textbf{ObjectId}: \textcolor{red}{Usuário} --  que executou.\\
       \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada.\\
   \end{tabular}\right.\\
   ~\\
   \left\{
   \begin{tabular}{l}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.\\
         \textbf{ObjectId}: \textcolor{red}{Usuário} --  que executou.\\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada.\\
   \end{tabular}\right.
   \end{array}
\right.
\]

\hyperlink{page.2}{\textbf {group\_id : }} \textcolor{red}{ ObjectId } - Id do  grupo. 

\pagebreak

\begin{center}
\textbf {Group schema}
\end{center}

\setstretch{1.5}

\textbf {ID : }  \textcolor{red}{ObjectId }- Id do registro \\
\textbf {Name: } \textcolor{red}{ String  } - Name co usuario \\
\textbf {date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date } - Date de Cadastro \\
\textbf {ren\_date: } \textcolor{red}{ Date }  -  Data de 

\textbf {email: } \textcolor{red}{ String } - Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit. 

\[
\text{accesslog: \textcolor{red}{ Array }}
  \left(
  \begin{array}{@{}ll}
  \left\{\begin{tabular}{l}
       \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.\\
       \textbf{ObjectId}: \textcolor{red}{Usuário} --  que executou.\\
       \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada.\\
   \end{tabular}\right.\\
   ~\\
   \left\{
   \begin{tabular}{l}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string}  Data -- da ocorrncia.\\
         \textbf{ObjectId}: \textcolor{red}{Usuário} --  que executou.\\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada.\\
   \end{tabular}\right.
   \end{array}
\right.
\]

\textcolor{blue} { \textbf {group\_id : }} \textcolor{red}{ ObjectId } - Id do  grupo. 


\end{document}
```

result should be like :

[image]

Comment: Regarding the bracket: you need \left\{ not just \left{.

Comment: @JohnWickerson: thanks, I used `\left\{ ` and ended with `}\right.`. But it shows just small brackage. Not convering entire content. please see https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5374a2ebeb2b8d651828ef64

Comment: Remove the } before \right.

Comment: @JohnWickerson: still issue persist, can you please see the link

Comment: You still need the full stop though. That is, "\right." not "\right"

Comment: @JohnWickerson: thanks dear, but I already tried with both cases. no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *should* get you going:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep]{\color{white}\textbf {User schema}}}

\[
  \text{Users} \left\{ \begin{tabular}{@{}p{.8\linewidth}@{}}
    \textbf{ID}:  \textcolor{red}{ObjectId} -- Id do registro \\
    \textbf{Name}: \textcolor{red}{String} -- Name co usuario \\
    \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{Date} -- Date de Cadastro \\
    \textbf{ren\_date}: \textcolor{red}{Date} -- Data de \\
    \textbf{email}: \parbox[t]{.9\linewidth}{\raggedright\textcolor{red}{String} -- Lorem ipsum dolorsitamet, consecteturadipisicingelit, sed do 
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minimveniam, exercitationullamcolaborisnisi ut 
      aliquipexeacommodoconsequat. Duisautereprehenderit in voluptatevelit esse cillumdolore eu fugiatnullapariatur. Occaecatcupidatat 
      non proident, sunt in culpa quiofficiadeseruntmollit.\strut} \\
    \textbf{accesslog}: \textcolor{red}{Array} \begin{tabular}[t]{@{\ }|l@{}}
      \strut \\[-\normalbaselineskip]
      $\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
         \textbf{user}: \textcolor{red}{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} --  Aço Executada. \\
       \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$ \\
      $\left\{\begin{tabular}{p{.7\linewidth}}
         \textbf{date}: \textcolor{red}{string} Data -- da ocorrncia. \\
         \textbf{user}: \textcolor{red}{ObjectId} -- que executou. \\
         \textbf{action}: \textcolor{red}{String} -- Aço Executada. \\
       \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace$
    \end{tabular}
  \end{tabular}\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
\]

\end{document}
```

It would be advisable, for [consistency](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764) and ease-of-updating, to define a macro that formats your list-like items. Something like

```
\newcommand{\entry}[1]{\textbf{#1}:}
\newcommand{\entrytype}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

and then use `\entry{ID} \entrytype{ObjectId} -- ...`.